# Java map with values limited by key's type parameter

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way in Java to have a map where the type parameter of a value is tied to the type parameter of a key? What I want to write is something like the following:

```
public class Foo {
    // This declaration won't compile - what should it be?
    private static Map<Class<T>, T> defaultValues;

    // These two methods are just fine
    public static <T> void setDefaultValue(Class<T> clazz, T value) {
        defaultValues.put(clazz, value);
    }

    public static <T> T getDefaultValue(Class<T> clazz) {
        return defaultValues.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

That is, I can store any default value against a Class object, provided the value's type matches that of the Class object. I don't see why this shouldn't be allowed since I can ensure when setting/getting values that the types are correct.

EDIT: Thanks to cletus for his answer. I don't actually need the type parameters on the map itself since I can ensure consistency in the methods which get/set values, even if it means using some slightly ugly casts.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You're not trying to implement Joshua Bloch's typesafe hetereogeneous container pattern are you?  Basically:

> ```
> public class Favorites {
>   private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites =
>     new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();
>
>   public <T> void setFavorite(Class<T> klass, T thing) {
>     favorites.put(klass, thing);
>   }
>
>   public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> klass) {
>     return klass.cast(favorites.get(klass));
>   }
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>     Favorites f = new Favorites();
>     f.setFavorite(String.class, "Java");
>     f.setFavorite(Integer.class, 0xcafebabe);
>     String s = f.getFavorite(String.class);
>     int i = f.getFavorite(Integer.class);
>   }
> }
> ```

From [Effective Java (2nd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) and [this presentation](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2006/coreplatform/TS-1512.pdf).

Comment: What if the value itself was Generic?  For instance, instead of storing `String`s and `int`s you need to store `PrettyPrinter<T>` where `T` is the type token used as the key in the map?

Comment: @Lucas Guava provides [`TypeToInstanceMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToInstanceMap.html) for this purpose; along with [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#classtoinstancemap) which replicates Bloch's `Favorites` API.

Answer (score 5):

The question and the answers made me come up with this solution: [Type-safe object map](http://blog.pdark.de/2010/05/28/type-safe-object-map/). Here is the code. Test case:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;


public class TypedMapTest {
    private final static TypedMapKey<String> KEY1 = new TypedMapKey<String>( "key1" );
    private final static TypedMapKey<List<String>> KEY2 = new TypedMapKey<List<String>>( "key2" );

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception {

        TypedMap map = new TypedMap();
        map.set( KEY1, null );
        assertNull( map.get( KEY1 ) );

        String expected = "Hallo";
        map.set( KEY1, expected );
        String value = map.get( KEY1 );
        assertEquals( expected, value );

        map.set( KEY2, null );
        assertNull( map.get( KEY2 ) );

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
        map.set( KEY2, list );
        List<String> valueList = map.get( KEY2 );
        assertEquals( list, valueList );
    }
}
```

This is the Key class. Note that the type `T` is never used in this class! It's purely for the purpose of type casting when reading the value out of the map. The field `key` only gives the key a name.

```
public class TypedMapKey<T> {
    private String key;

    public TypedMapKey( String key ) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ( ( key == null ) ? 0 : key.hashCode() );
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj ) {
        if( this == obj ) {
            return true;
        }
        if( obj == null ) {
            return false;
        }
        if( getClass() != obj.getClass() ) {
            return false;
        }
        TypedMapKey<?> other = (TypedMapKey<?>) obj;
        if( key == null ) {
            if( other.key != null ) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if( !key.equals( other.key ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

TypedMap.java:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class TypedMap implements Map<Object, Object> {
    private Map<Object, Object> delegate;

    public TypedMap( Map<Object, Object> delegate ) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public TypedMap() {
        this.delegate = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public <T> T get( TypedMapKey<T> key ) {
        return (T) delegate.get( key );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public <T> T remove( TypedMapKey<T> key ) {
        return (T) delegate.remove( key );
    }

    public <T> void set( TypedMapKey<T> key, T value ) {
        delegate.put( key, value );
    }

    // --- Only calls to delegates below

    public void clear() {
        delegate.clear();
    }

    public boolean containsKey( Object key ) {
        return delegate.containsKey( key );
    }

    public boolean containsValue( Object value ) {
        return delegate.containsValue( value );
    }

    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet() {
        return delegate.entrySet();
    }

    public boolean equals( Object o ) {
        return delegate.equals( o );
    }

    public Object get( Object key ) {
        return delegate.get( key );
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return delegate.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return delegate.isEmpty();
    }

    public Set<Object> keySet() {
        return delegate.keySet();
    }

    public Object put( Object key, Object value ) {
        return delegate.put( key, value );
    }

    public void putAll( Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> m ) {
        delegate.putAll( m );
    }

    public Object remove( Object key ) {
        return delegate.remove( key );
    }

    public int size() {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    public Collection<Object> values() {
        return delegate.values();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it directly.  You'll need to write a wrapper class around `Map<Class, Object>` to enforce that Object will be `instanceof` Class.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a class which stores a map of type safe key to a value, and cast when necessary. The cast in `get` method is safe, as after using `new Key<CharSequence>()`, it's not possible to safely cast it to `Key<String>` or `Key<Object>`, so the type system enforces the correct usage of a class.

The `Key` class needs to be final, as otherwise an user could override `equals` and cause type-unsafety if two elements with different types were to be equal. Alternatively, it's possible to override `equals` to be final if you want to use inheritance despite the issues with it.

```
public final class TypeMap {
    private final Map<Key<?>, Object> m = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> T get(Key<? extends T> key) {
        // Safe, as it's not possible to safely change the Key generic type,
        // hash map cannot be accessed by an user, and this class being final
        // to prevent serialization attacks.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T value = (T) m.get(key);
        return value;
    }

    public <T> void put(Key<? super T> key, T value) {
        m.put(key, value);
    }

    public static final class Key<T> {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below 2 classes, Map class: ***GenericMap***, Map-Key class: ***GenericKey***

**For example:**

```
// Create a key includine Type definition
public static final GenericKey<HttpServletRequest> REQUEST = new GenericKey<>(HttpServletRequest.class, "HttpRequestKey");

public void example(HttpServletRequest requestToSave)
{
    GenericMap map = new GenericMap();

    // Saving value
    map.put(REQUEST, requestToSave);

    // Getting value
    HttpServletRequest request = map.get(REQUEST);
}
```

**Advantages**

- It forces the user to put and get correct types by compilation error
- It's doing casing for you inside
- Generic Key helps to avoid write the class type each time you calling ***put(..)*** or ***get***
- No typo mistakes, like if key is 'String' type

### GenericMap

```
public class GenericMap
{  
    private Map<String, Object> storageMap;

    protected GenericMap()
    {
        storageMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public <T> T get(GenericKey<T> key)
    {
        Object value = storageMap.get(key.getKey());
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return key.getClassType().cast(value);
    }

    /**
     * @param key    GenericKey object with generic type - T (it can be any type)
     * @param object value to put in the map, the type of 'object' mast be - T
     */
    public <T> void put(GenericKey<T> key, T object)
    {
        T castedObject = key.getClassType().cast(object);
        storageMap.put(key.getKey(), castedObject);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return storageMap.toString();
    }
}
```

### GenericKey

```
public class GenericKey<T>
{
    private Class<T> classType;
    private String key;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private GenericKey()
    {
    }

    public GenericKey(Class<T> iClassType, String iKey)
    {
        this.classType = iClassType;
        this.key = iKey;
    }

    public Class<T> getClassType()
    {
        return classType;
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[classType=" + classType + ", key=" + key + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`T` as a type must be defined generically in the class instance. The following example works:

```
public class Test<T> {

    private Map<Class<T>, T> defaultValues;

    public void setDefaultValue(Class<T> clazz, T value) {
        defaultValues.put(clazz, value);
    }

    public T getDefaultValue(Class<T> clazz) {
        return defaultValues.get(clazz);
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can use Paul Tomblin's answer, and wrap the `Map` with your own object which will enforce this type of generics.

Comment: The poster wants to have a mapping from arbitrary classes to default values of those classes. This allows a mapping from only one class.