# Generic Map of Generic key/values with related types

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm trying to create a generic type that keeps a map of the versions of itself that have been created for later use. Effectively, it's an singleton pattern where there's one instance per type. The code I have so far is:

```
public class FieldBinder<T> {
    static final Map<Class<? extends Object>,FieldBinder<? extends Object>> instanceMap = 
        new HashMap<Class<? extends Object>,FieldBinder<? extends Object>>();

    private FieldBinder() {}

    synchronized public static <V extends Object> FieldBinder<V> getInstance(Class<V> klass) {
        if(!instanceMap.containsKey(klass)) {
            instanceMap.put(klass, new FieldBinder<V>());
        }
        return (FieldBinder<V>)instanceMap.get(klass);
    }
}
```

However, I'm still unsure that I'm "doing it right". It feels like I should be able to specify that the collection is (Class -> FieldBinder). The fact that the IDE is warning about the return statement only reinforces this thought.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540/java-map-with-values-limited-by-keys-type-parameter) seems very closely related, but just far enough away that I can't figure out how to apply the information in it to my own problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. There's no "better" way of doing it (if there is such a thing is "better" in code, which is another issue..)

Minor fixes:

- `<V extends Object>` is equivalent to `V` which is less verbose
- `Class<? extends Object>` is equivalent to `Class<?>` which is less verbose
- You can use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation to tell your compiler that the cast is safe

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can be done without having an unchecked cast somewhere.  You would need something similar to Haskell's [existential types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type), which Java does not have.

You could make the *client* perform the unchecked cast instead...

```
synchronized public static <V> FieldBinder<V>
getInstance(Class<V> klass, Class<FieldBinder<V>> binderKlass) {
    if(!instanceMap.containsKey(klass)) {
        instanceMap.put(klass, new FieldBinder<V>());
    }
    return binderKlass.cast(instanceMap.get(klass));
}
```

Now if the client passes a `Class<FieldBinder<V>>` to the `getInstance()` method you can avoid the unchecked cast within `getInstance()`.

Unfortunately creating a `Class<FieldBinder<V>>` itself requires an unchecked cast.

```
Class<FieldBinder<Integer>> binderKlass =
    (Class<FieldBinder<Integer>>) (Class<?>) FieldBinder.class;
BinderAssociator.getInstance(Integer.class, binderKlass);
```

Answer (score 3):

RHSeeger, I got your original question. I found no solution for the problem. What you can try to play with is a MyMap class, which makes the binding as you request. However with this map two problems arise:

1. As it is declared as `MyMap<?>`, one cannot add something with a given type to it. That's dummy and I refer you to [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ302B) (see case study 3) for more details.
2. As map has connection between key and value, one cannot add two independent objects of any type (two `<?>` refer to different types) because these two types may be not connected.

While playing I have seen some errors, which I could not explain myself. I think, everything goes into the fact (as I mentioned before) that we try to deal with 2-nd level parametrization.

```
    class FieldBinder<T> {
        static class MyMap<M> extends HashMap<Class<M>, FieldBinder<M>> {
        }
        static final MyMap<?> instanceMap1 = new MyMap<Object>();
        static final Map<Class<?>, FieldBinder<?>> instanceMap2 = new HashMap<Class<?>, FieldBinder<?>>();
        public static <V> void test() {
            Class<V> c1 = null;
            FieldBinder<V> f1 = null;
            Class<?> c2 = null;
            FieldBinder<?> f2 = null;
            instanceMap1.put(c1, f1); // error (see 1)
            instanceMap1.put(c2, f2); // error (see 2)
            instanceMap2.put(c1, f1); // ok
            instanceMap2.put(c2, f2); // ok
            instanceMap2.put(c1, f2); // wish to be an error, but ok
            instanceMap2.put(c2, f1); // wish to be an error, but ok
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have a pretty good grasp on the fact that Java generics are just not up to the task I'm looking to accomplish now, and your answer helped solidify that. I think what I'd really like to see would be the ability to say
.... 
static final <?1> Map<Class<?1>, FieldBinder<?1>> instanceMap2 = new <?1> HashMap<Class<?1>, FieldBinder<?1>>();
....
Where the <?1> means "any type", but binds that type to a variable that can be used later.

Answer (score 1):

The example you refer tells, how to recover the type (class) of object, while you need to recover the type (class) of parametrization. That is not possible.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you're saying, then that's not at all what I'm doing. What I want is to tell the compiler "this is a map from 'Class<?>' to 'FieldBinder<?>' where both ? must be the same. As such, when I pull out something using a key of ?=xyz, I can safely convery the value to ?=xyz, since the compiler can limit me to only putting things in that way. It's all compile time information, it just seems that the compiler can't handle it.