# How can I say "these two generic types are the same" in a map?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method `toString( Object )` which delegates the conversion to handlers. The handlers are defined like this:

```
public interface IToStringService<T> {
    public String toString( T value );
}
```

The code looks like this:

```
// (1) How can I say that these two wildcards must in fact be the same type?
private Map<Class<?>, IToStringService<?>> specialHandlers = Maps.newHashMap();

// Generic method, must accept Object (any type really)
@Override
public String toString( Object value ) {

    if( null == value ) {
        return "null";
    }

    Class<?> type = value.getClass();
    if( type.isArray() ) {
        return arrayToString( value );
    }

    // (2) How can I get rid of this SuppressWarnings?
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    IToStringService<Object> handler = (IToStringService<Object>) specialHandlers.get( type );

    if( null != handler ) {
        return handler.toString( value );
    }

    return value.toString();
}

public <T> void addSpecialHandler( Class<T> type, IToStringService<T> handler ) {
    specialHandlers.put( type, handler );
}
```

And one implementation looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "rawtypes" ) // Can't add generics to "Class" or I get compile errors when calling DefaultToStringService.addSpecialHandler() :-(
public class ClassToStringService implements IToStringService<Class> {

    @Override
    public String toString( Class value ) {
        return value == null ? "null" : value.getName();
    }
}
```

I have several problems here:

1. How can I say that the handlers in the `specialHandlers` map must match the type used as the key?
2. How can I use the same information inside the method to avoid casting and `@SuppressWarnings`?
3. When I change `ClassToStringService` to implement `IToStringService<Class<?>>`, I get a compile error when calling `addSpecialHandler( Class.class, new ClassToStringService() );` How do I solve this?

Comment: You want to enforce that the Generics of the Key is the same as the Generics of the Value. Well, you cannot do that in a Map. But since you are controlling what is put into the Map, do you really that restriction?

Comment: @Luciano: Thought so but sometimes, someone knows a trick. What about the last point?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic Map of Generic key/values with related types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208317/generic-map-of-generic-key-values-with-related-types)

Comment: I don't know about the last point, maybe you hit the limits of Generics (which are far from perfect).

Comment: Your question is somewhat related to Item 29 of Effective Java by J. Bloch.  I could not come up with anything better than what you did.  I concur with @Luciano: you are probably doing as well as you can with generics and you control all access to your map, so all the warning suppression is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Java. I'll explain why. ? extends are called existential types in type theory but Java has a limited form of them. ? extends X means that there exist Y such that Y extend X. We can rewrite  `Map<Class<?>, IToStringService<?>>` as:

```
Map<Class<(exists T1 extends Object)>, IToStringService<(exist T2 extends Object)>>
```

But we want:

```
Map<(exists T extends Object Class<T>, IToStringService<T>>
```

We can't express this in Java because existential quantifier can't be specified explicitly in Java. However, In Scala you can do this.