# How to iterate over a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I use a JSON library called `JSONObject` (I don't mind switching if I need to).

I know how to iterate over `JSONArrays`, but when I parse JSON data from Facebook I don't get an array, only a `JSONObject`, but I need to be able to access an item via its index, such as `JSONObject[0]` to get the first one, and I can't figure out how to do it.

```
{
   "http://http://url.com/": {
      "id": "http://http://url.com//"
   },
   "http://url2.co/": {
      "id": "http://url2.com//",
      "shares": 16
   }
   ,
   "http://url3.com/": {
      "id": "http://url3.com//",
      "shares": 16
   }
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56223923/10268067

Answer (score 696):

Maybe this will help:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(contents.trim());
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
          // do something with jsonObject here      
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful everyone, jObject.keys() returns the iterator with reverse index order.

Comment: @macio.Jun Nevertheless, the order doesn't matter in maps of properties: keys in `JSONObject` are unordered and your assertion was a simple reflection of a private implementation ;)

Comment: What to use when we need all keys sequentially ?

Comment: Slight quibble: doesn't this lead to doing the key lookup twice?  Maybe better to do 'Object o = jObject.get(key)', then check its type and then use it, without having to call get(key) again.

Comment: how do you actually retrieve the id key? @caligari

Comment: @Tom [For-Each loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) are useful when iterating over a collection: `for (String key : keys)`

Comment: I would just like to mention, for people that have the problem of "keys()" method not getting resolved (saying that the JSONObject doesn't have that method): you can instead type `jsonObject.keySet().iterator()` and it works fine.

Comment: If you want an order it must be sent as a Array not a Keyed Array, if you want you can add an object to each Array item which is a Keyed Array.

Answer (score 106):

for my case i found iterating the `names()` works well

```
for(int i = 0; i<jobject.names().length(); i++){
    Log.v(TAG, "key = " + jobject.names().getString(i) + " value = " + jobject.get(jobject.names().getString(i)));
}
```

Comment: Although this example isn't really understood as `Iterating` in Java, it works quite well! Thanks.

Comment: Great answer. It works perfectly for almost all types of json objects nested or not. !

Comment: What is `Log. v() `? Which library it belongs to?

Comment: @tarekahf Android SDK

Answer (score 85):

I will avoid iterator as they can add/remove object during iteration, also for clean code use for loop.  it will be simply clean & fewer lines.

Using Java 8 and Lamda [Update 4/2/2019]

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    jsonObj.keySet().forEach(keyStr ->
    {
        Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);
        System.out.println("key: "+ keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);

        //for nested objects iteration if required
        //if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)
        //    printJsonObject((JSONObject)keyvalue);
    });
}
```

Using old way [Update 4/2/2019]

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    for (String keyStr : jsonObj.keySet()) {
        Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);

        //Print key and value
        System.out.println("key: "+ keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);

        //for nested objects iteration if required
        //if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)
        //    printJsonObject((JSONObject)keyvalue);
    }
}
```

Original Answer

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
public static void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    for (Object key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
        //based on you key types
        String keyStr = (String)key;
        Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);

        //Print key and value
        System.out.println("key: "+ keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);

        //for nested objects iteration if required
        if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)
            printJsonObject((JSONObject)keyvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: They never said they were using org.json.simple (which is a google library). The standard org.json.JSONObject forces you to use an iterator, unfortunately.

Comment: You saved my but here!

Comment: org.json.JSONObject does not have keySet()

Comment: What version are you looking? https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#keySet--

Comment: Nice answer. Easy to get spoiled by options. :) All options just work flawlessly. Brilliant.

Comment: Nice use of recursion. I used a similar pattern, adding JSONArray testing to it, including JSONObject recursion within the array elements. The String became the fall-thru case.

Answer (score 80):

Can't believe that there is no more simple and secured solution instead of using an iterator in this answers...

JSONObject `names ()` method returns a `JSONArray` of the `JSONObject` keys, so you can simply walk though it in loop:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject ();
JSONArray keys = object.names ();

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length (); i++) {
   
   String key = keys.getString (i); // Here's your key
   String value = object.getString (key); // Here's your value
   
}
```

Comment: what is object here?

Comment: It's `JSONObject`. Something like `JSONObject object = new JSONObject ("{\"key1\",\"value1\"}");`. But do not put raw json to it, add items in it with `put ()` method: `object.put ("key1", "value1");`.

Comment: Thanks Sir It is very helpful to me

Comment: @GanesanJ glad to hear it)

Comment: This is by far the cleanest answer, +1

Comment: still unordered :((

Comment: @CodeToLife it's not about ordering, it's about iterate. You can only order JSON object using another loop with `JSONAarray` of your `JSONObject` keys ordered in order you need (alphabetically, etc.).

Answer (score 19):

```
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonObject.values().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
 jsonChildObject = iterator.next();

 // Do whatever you want with jsonChildObject 

  String id = (String) jsonChildObject.get("id");
}
```

Comment: `jsonChildObject = iterator.next();` should probably define `jsonChildObject`, like `JSONObject jsonChildObject = iterator.next();`, no?

Comment: I like this solution, but declaring `Iterator<JSONObject>` will give a warning. I'd replace it with the generic `<?>` and do a cast on the call to `next()`. Also, I'd use `getString("id")` instead of `get("id")` to save doing a cast.

Answer (score 15):

org.json.JSONObject now has a keySet() method which returns a `Set<String>` and can easily be looped through with a for-each.

```
for(String key : jsonObject.keySet())
```

Comment: I think this is the most convenient solution. Thanks for advice :)

Comment: Could you complete your example?

Answer (score 10):

Most of the answers here are for flat JSON structures, in case you have a JSON which might have nested JSONArrays or Nested JSONObjects, the real complexity arises. The following code snippet takes care of such a business requirement. It takes a hash map, and hierarchical JSON with both nested JSONArrays and JSONObjects and updates the JSON with the data in the hash map

```
public void updateData(JSONObject fullResponse, HashMap<String, String> mapToUpdate) {

    fullResponse.keySet().forEach(keyStr -> {
        Object keyvalue = fullResponse.get(keyStr);

        if (keyvalue instanceof JSONArray) {
            updateData(((JSONArray) keyvalue).getJSONObject(0), mapToUpdate);
        } else if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject) {
            updateData((JSONObject) keyvalue, mapToUpdate);
        } else {
            // System.out.println("key: " + keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);
            if (mapToUpdate.containsKey(keyStr)) {
                fullResponse.put(keyStr, mapToUpdate.get(keyStr));
            }
        }
    });

}
```

You have to notice here that the return type of this is void, but sice objects are passed as refernce this change is refelected to the caller.

Answer (score 7):

First put this somewhere:

```
private <T> Iterable<T> iteratorToIterable(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return new Iterable<T>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return iterator;
        }
    };
}
```

Or if you have access to Java8, just this:

```
private <T> Iterable<T> iteratorToIterable(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return () -> iterator;
}
```

Then simply iterate over the object's keys and values:

```
for (String key : iteratorToIterable(object.keys())) {
    JSONObject entry = object.getJSONObject(key);
    // ...
```

Comment: I voted for this, but "String key : ...." doesn't compile, and there doesn't seem to be a way to avoid an unchecked cast warning on the iterator. Stupid iterators.

Answer (score 2):

I made a small recursive function that goes through the entire json object and saves the key path and its value.

```
// My stored keys and values from the json object
HashMap<String,String> myKeyValues = new HashMap<String,String>();

// Used for constructing the path to the key in the json object
Stack<String> key_path = new Stack<String>();

// Recursive function that goes through a json object and stores 
// its key and values in the hashmap 
private void loadJson(JSONObject json){
    Iterator<?> json_keys = json.keys();

    while( json_keys.hasNext() ){
        String json_key = (String)json_keys.next();

        try{
            key_path.push(json_key);
            loadJson(json.getJSONObject(json_key));
       }catch (JSONException e){
           // Build the path to the key
           String key = "";
           for(String sub_key: key_path){
               key += sub_key+".";
           }
           key = key.substring(0,key.length()-1);

           System.out.println(key+": "+json.getString(json_key));
           key_path.pop();
           myKeyValues.put(key, json.getString(json_key));
        }
    }
    if(key_path.size() > 0){
        key_path.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 and lambda, cleaner:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(contents.trim());

jObject.keys().forEachRemaining(k ->
{

});
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: It iterates only the keys but you still need to get the value, so you can use jObject.get(k);

Comment: I get "Cast from null to consumer requires minimum API 24"

Answer (score 2):

I once had a json that had ids that needed to be incremented by one since they were 0-indexed and that was breaking Mysql auto-increment.

So for each object I wrote this code - might be helpful to someone:

```
public static void  incrementValue(JSONObject obj, List<String> keysToIncrementValue) {
        Set<String> keys = obj.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            Object ob = obj.get(key);

            if (keysToIncrementValue.contains(key)) {
                obj.put(key, (Integer)obj.get(key) + 1);
            }

            if (ob instanceof JSONObject) {
                incrementValue((JSONObject) ob, keysToIncrementValue);
            }
            else if (ob instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) ob;
                for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    Object arrObj = arr.get(0);
                    if (arrObj instanceof JSONObject) {
                        incrementValue((JSONObject) arrObj, keysToIncrementValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
JSONObject object = ....
incrementValue(object, Arrays.asList("id", "product_id", "category_id", "customer_id"));
```

this can be transformed to work for JSONArray as parent object too

Answer (score 2):

We used below set of code to iterate over `JSONObject` fields

```
Iterator iterator = jsonObject.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext())  {
        Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = (Entry<String, JsonElement>) iterator.next();
        processedJsonObject.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my small method to log JsonObject fields, and get some stings. See if it can be usefull.

```
object JsonParser {

val TAG = "JsonParser"
 /**
 * parse json object
 * @param objJson
 * @return  Map<String, String>
 * @throws JSONException
 */
@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun parseJson(objJson: Any?): Map<String, String> {
    val map = HashMap<String, String>()

    // If obj is a json array
    if (objJson is JSONArray) {
        for (i in 0 until objJson.length()) {
            parseJson(objJson[i])
        }
    } else if (objJson is JSONObject) {
        val it: Iterator<*> = objJson.keys()
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            val key = it.next().toString()
            // If you get an array
            when (val jobject = objJson[key]) {
                is JSONArray -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, " JSONArray: $jobject")
                    parseJson(jobject)
                }
                is JSONObject -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, " JSONObject: $jobject")
                    parseJson(jobject)
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, " adding to map: $key $jobject")
                    map[key] = jobject.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return map
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked fine for me. Please help me if tuning can be done. This gets all the keys even from the nested JSON objects.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = ""; // Sample JSON to be parsed

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(s);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> parameterKeys = new ArrayList<String>(obj.keySet());
        List<String>  result = null;
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str : parameterKeys) {
            keys.add(str);
            result = this.addNestedKeys(obj, keys, str);
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static List<String> addNestedKeys(JSONObject obj, List<String> keys, String key) {
    if (isNestedJsonAnArray(obj.get(key))) {
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj.get(key);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject arrayObj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(arrayObj.keySet());
                for (String s : list) {
                    putNestedKeysToList(keys, key, s);
                    addNestedKeys(arrayObj, keys, s);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                LOG.error("", e);
            }
        }
    } else if (isNestedJsonAnObject(obj.get(key))) {
        JSONObject arrayObj = (JSONObject) obj.get(key);
        List<String> nestedKeys = new ArrayList<>(arrayObj.keySet());
        for (String s : nestedKeys) {
            putNestedKeysToList(keys, key, s);
            addNestedKeys(arrayObj, keys, s);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

private static void putNestedKeysToList(List<String> keys, String key, String s) {
    if (!keys.contains(key + Constants.JSON_KEY_SPLITTER + s)) {
        keys.add(key + Constants.JSON_KEY_SPLITTER + s);
    }
}



private static boolean isNestedJsonAnObject(Object object) {
    boolean bool = false;
    if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
        bool = true;
    }
    return bool;
}

private static boolean isNestedJsonAnArray(Object object) {
    boolean bool = false;
    if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
        bool = true;
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is is another working solution to the problem:

```
public void test (){

    Map<String, String> keyValueStore = new HasMap<>();
    Stack<String> keyPath = new Stack();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject("thisYourJsonObject");
    keyValueStore = getAllXpathAndValueFromJsonObject(json, keyValueStore, keyPath);
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> map : keyValueStore.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(map.getKey() + ":" + map.getValue());
    }   
}

public Map<String, String> getAllXpathAndValueFromJsonObject(JSONObject json, Map<String, String> keyValueStore, Stack<String> keyPath) {
    Set<String> jsonKeys = json.keySet();
    for (Object keyO : jsonKeys) {
        String key = (String) keyO;
        keyPath.push(key);
        Object object = json.get(key);

        if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
            getAllXpathAndValueFromJsonObject((JSONObject) object, keyValueStore, keyPath);
        }

        if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
            doJsonArray((JSONArray) object, keyPath, keyValueStore, json, key);
        }

        if (object instanceof String || object instanceof Boolean || object.equals(null)) {
            String keyStr = "";

            for (String keySub : keyPath) {
                keyStr += keySub + ".";
            }

            keyStr = keyStr.substring(0, keyStr.length() - 1);

            keyPath.pop();

            keyValueStore.put(keyStr, json.get(key).toString());
        }
    }

    if (keyPath.size() > 0) {
        keyPath.pop();
    }

    return keyValueStore;
}

public void doJsonArray(JSONArray object, Stack<String> keyPath, Map<String, String> keyValueStore, JSONObject json,
        String key) {
    JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) object;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        keyPath.push(Integer.toString(i));
        Object obj = arr.get(i);
        if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
            getAllXpathAndValueFromJsonObject((JSONObject) obj, keyValueStore, keyPath);
        }

        if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
            doJsonArray((JSONArray) obj, keyPath, keyValueStore, json, key);
        }

        if (obj instanceof String || obj instanceof Boolean || obj.equals(null)) {
            String keyStr = "";

            for (String keySub : keyPath) {
                keyStr += keySub + ".";
            }

            keyStr = keyStr.substring(0, keyStr.length() - 1);

            keyPath.pop();

            keyValueStore.put(keyStr , json.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
    if (keyPath.size() > 0) {
        keyPath.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a for-each loop over the set of keys. Given you have a String value of JSON called "text":

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(text);
for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
    // Print out each value to verify this code
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON data you provided is an object where each key is a URL and the corresponding value is another object. If you want to access items by index, you may want to convert the outer object into an array. However, keep in mind that in JavaScript, objects don't have a specific order, so converting it to an array might not preserve the order.

Assuming you're working in a JavaScript environment, you can convert the outer object to an array and then access elements by index. Here's an example:

```
const jsonData = {
   "http://url.com/": {
      "id": "http://url.com//"
   },
   "http://url2.co/": {
      "id": "http://url2.com//",
      "shares": 16
   },
   "http://url3.com/": {
      "id": "http://url3.com//",
      "shares": 16
   }
};

// Convert the object to an array
const jsonArray = Object.entries(jsonData).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));

// Access the first item
const firstItem = jsonArray[0];

// Accessing specific properties of the first item
const firstItemId = firstItem.value.id;
const firstItemShares = firstItem.value.shares;

console.log(firstItemId);      // Output: http://url.com//
console.log(firstItemShares);  // Output: undefined (shares property is not present in the first item)
```

In this example, Object.entries is used to convert the object into an array of key-value pairs, and map is used to transform it into an array of objects. Now you can access items by index in the jsonArray. Keep in mind that if the order of items is important, you may want to reconsider the structure of your JSON data or use an array in the first place if possible.