# Android JSONObject - How can I loop through a flat JSON object to get each key and value

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

How I can get each item's key and value without knowing the key nor value beforehand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Use the [`keys()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) iterator to iterate over all the properties, and call [`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) for each.

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: You can't use the short form for (String s: json.keys()) { ... } It's a real shame that neither JSONArray nor JSONObject are iterable. :-(

Comment: what is json here? Json Object, Json Array or anthing else?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela it's a JSONObject as specified in the question

Answer (score 69):

Short version of Franci's answer:

```
for(Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();iter.hasNext();) {
    String key = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is json here? Json Object, Json Array or anthing else?

Comment: json is JsonObject

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela pretty sure the OP asked how to loop through a json object.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to use an `Iterator` to loop through the keys to get their values.

Here's a Kotlin implementation, you will realised that the way I got the string is using `optString()`, which is expecting a String or a nullable value.

```
val keys = jsonObject.keys()
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    val key = keys.next()
    val value = targetJson.optString(key)        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shold use the `keys()` or `names()` method.  `keys()` will give you an iterator containing all the String property names in the object while `names()` will give you an array of all key String names.

You can get the JSONObject documentation here

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the JSONObject reference:

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Without actually using the object, it looks like using either getNames() or keys() which returns an Iterator is the way to go.

Comment: Wrong link. The `JSONObject` in Android doesn't have `getNames()`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html