# Is this a valid JSON?

Tags: android, json

I am successfully parsing a json which looks like this, which in this particular case represents an array with 2 items:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mark"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to parse one like this:

```
{
  "items": {

    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John"     
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,      
      "name": "Mark"
    }

  }
}
```

As you can see, the second json is pretty similar to previous one, except after `items` it begins with "{", which means it is an object not an array, but I need that data to treat like an array.

Is this an invalid json, or I am missing something?

**EDIT:**
Ok, got it. The json is valid.
Let me please reformulate the question.
What I am actually looking for is how could I get the second json into a list of items.
Somewhere in the code I am doing this:

```
ItemsResponse itemsResponse = JsonMarshaller.fromJson(ItemsResponse.class, response);
```

and the ItemsResponse class:

```
public class ItemsResponse {
    private List<Item> items;
    // getters and setters
}
```

but it fails with an exception which says that the beginning of the json is an object, not an array.

**SOLUTION:**
The correct way is to use a `Map` instead of the `List`:

```
public class ItemsResponse {
    private Map<String, Item> items;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Both are valid Json. First one is fine if you want to iterate.

Comment: For checking valid josn.. check http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: JSON is correct see this http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: To check validity of json, use http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Use http://www.jsonlint.org/ to check wether a json is valid or not?

Comment: pro.jsonlint.com // put your json over here ... it will tell you that you have the valid json or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android JSON parsing of multiple JSONObjects inside JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606572/android-json-parsing-of-multiple-jsonobjects-inside-jsonobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the answer of Ahmad Dwaik 'Warlock' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606572/android-json-parsing-of-multiple-jsonobjects-inside-jsonobject)
You can check your json [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yep, categories and keys, that is what I was missing. Never had a chance to parse a json formatted in this way. Thank you.