# Parse JSON Android convert jsonObject

Tags: android, parsing, json

I have a problem with JSON
I get a json since https://proxyepn-test.epnbn.net/wsapi/epn

But when I want to display a single data eg "name".
The console displays:

**Log**

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for Name
org.json.JSONException: Value status at 0 of the type java.lang.String can not be converted to JSONObject
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks.

here is my code :

```
String test2 = test.execute(restURL).get().toString();
        Log.i("result",test2);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(test2);
        String data = obj.getString("data");
        Log.i("testjson",data);
        String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("data").getString("Name");
        Log.i("testjsondata",pageName);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(test2);
JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("data");
Iterator<String> iterator = data.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String key = iterator.next();
        String Name = data.getString(key);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply
I can now have each block my json
But how do you have only data on a category, such as "Name"
Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(test2);
JSONObject data=obj.getJSONobject("data");
JSONObject ob1=obj.getJSONobject("1");
String pageName = ob1.getString("Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your next level of JSONObject (labeled as "1","2","3".. from response).

It seems like issue in Json response structure you shared. why cann't it be array inside "data"?

Then you can easily read data as JSONArray with those objects as ("1","2","3"..) array item.

Else

[Android JSON parsing of multiple JSONObjects inside JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606572/android-json-parsing-of-multiple-jsonobjects-inside-jsonobject)