# How to get data from JsonObject and set as Array on RecyclerView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a project that was previously done by another developer. I continue to call API for the project. I've followed his way. But, I get stuck when I want to retrieve `JsonArray` and show it into `RecyclerView`.
How I can to get the data from `JSONArray`.

**Interface:**

```
interface TripService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("driver/getAvailableTripList")
    fun availableTripList(@Field("page") page : String): Call<JsonObject>
}
```

**TripServiceHandler:**

```
class TripServiceHandler {
    private var instance: TripService? = null
    // Singleton instance to access through the application

    init {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = TripFactory().createJourney(TripService::class.java)
        }
    }


    // Method for Driver Balance Service
    fun availableTripList(page: String, listener: ServerCallbackListener) =
            this.instance?.let {this.instance!!.availableTripList(page).enqueue(RetrofitCallBackHandler.getHandler(listener)) 
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
private fun getAvailableTrip(){
    showLoading()
    TripServiceHandler().availableTripList("1", availableTripHandler)
}

private var availableTripHandler: ServerCallbackListener = object : ServerCallbackListener {
    override fun onSuccess(baseResponse: JsonObject?) {
        hideLoading()
        val data = baseResponse!!.getAsJsonObject(AppConstants.KEY_DATA)

    }

    override fun onFailure(message: String?) {
        showMessageBar(message, SnackBarUtility.MessageType.ERROR)
    }

}
```

**Data Model:**

```
class Trip : Serializable {

    @SerializedName("tid")
    var tripId: String? = null

    @SerializedName("max_passengers")
    var maxPass: String? = null

    @SerializedName("driver_revenue")
    var priceTrip: String? = null

    @SerializedName("origin_coordinate")
    var originCoordinate: List<Coordinate>? = null

    @SerializedName("destination_coordinate")
    var destCoordinate: List<Coordinate>? = null
}
```

the jsonArray

```
"rows": [
            {
                "tid": "44551",
                "did": null,
                "status": 1,
                "leaving_time": "1547093186",
                "max_passengers": 12,
                "total_revenue": 0,
                "driver_revenue": 0,
                "origin_coordinate": {
                    "x": 1.43762623,
                    "y": 103.80153311
                },
                "destination_coordinate": {
                    "x": 1.29481854,
                    "y": 103.78735487
                },
                "total_requests": 12,
                "destination_geom": "0101000020E610000048F0284063F25940854F5F1901BFF43F",
                "origin_geom": "0101000020E61000002AB6CC40C7F25940032A19ECF7E4F63F",
                "stops": [
                    {
                        "sid": "46969",
                        "count": "4",
                        "order_seq": 1,
                        "mode": 0,
                        "name": "Woodlands Ave 4",
                        "description": "Blk 532",
                        "coordinate": {
                            "x": 1.43059181782,
                            "y": 103.792699721
                        },
                        "eta_time": "1547093186",
                        "leaving_time": "1547093366"
                    },
```

Comment: What is the response of this api "driver/getAvailableTripList" ?

Comment: have u tried to print out your data when you processed an json object type value

Comment: yes, i print the data on Logcat @DemiDust

Comment: what is the log? it might help in finding your issue @Mavisa9

Comment: the log is the JsonArray of the api. i already my Question and put the data on it @DemiDust

Comment: try this, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103987/parse-json-android-convert-jsonobject

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079505/converting-json-string-to-java-object

Comment: Hi @DemiDust i've tried that. but i still confuse. can you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186079/discussion-between-mavisa9-and-demidust).

Answer (score 1):

As I have seen, your data should be a JSONobject type value already and since you are using serialized name i assume you are using Gson library for it.

First, make another model beforehand to contain your List (since it passed in rows)

```
data class TripList:Serializeable{
    @("rows")
    myList:List<Trip> = ArrayList()
}
```

Then, you can try this

```
val tripList = gson.fromJson(data, TripList::class.java)
```

Your tripList will then be TripList type of class, access your list with tripList.myList. Hope it will work for your solution