# Android JSON Object Parsing

Tags: android, json

I have some sample json data with objects only.

```
{
  "0": {
    "image": null,
    "title": "Government to issue new ₹500 and ₹2,000 notes from Nov 10 ",
    "time": "10:46 pm ",
    "date": "08 Nov ",
    "content": "The government will start issuing the new ₹500 and ₹2,000 currency notes from November 10, said ...",
    "link": "https://full-story.newsinshorts.com/v1/article/f0619b6a-738e-4470-897f-4e5cdad3ea52-1 "
  },
  "1": {
    "image": null,
    "title": "₹1,000, ₹5,000 and ₹10,000 notes were demonetised in 1978 ",
    "time": "10:20 pm ",
    "date": "08 Nov ",
    "content": "The Indian government had demonetised the ₹1,000, ₹5,000 and ₹10,000 currency notes in 1978 ...",
    "link": null
  },
  ...

}
```

It has more objects than what is visible. How can I proceed with parsing this data?

Comment: You can try [this sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606572/android-json-parsing-of-multiple-jsonobjects-inside-jsonobject), I see it nearly same your json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Why you trying to parse make it as model class using GSON and use that model

Comment: @Saveen - How do you make an Object named `0`?

Comment: @Cricket_007 Sir this json is not correct, Need json array

Comment: @Saveen The JSON is perfectly valid. Read the link in the first comment on how to parse. Gson cannot be used

Comment: if something is being repeated in json object its better to have it inside an jsonarray and run a loop to grab all data inside the pojo.

Comment: is it solved ??

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I couldnt understand your solution as I am using volley to parse. The problem is still not solved. Thanks everyone and more answers please.

Comment: it does not matter you using volley..check answer how to parse

Answer (score 0):

I assume the above **JSON** is gotten from a given source say **web server**. This is how I would handle it

```
   String yourJSON = {
          "0": {
            "image": null,
            "title": "Government to issue new ₹500 and ₹2,000 notes from Nov 10 ",
            "time": "10:46 pm ",
            "date": "08 Nov ",
            "content": "The government will start issuing the new ₹500 and ₹2,000 currency notes from November 10, said ...",
            "link": "https://full-story.newsinshorts.com/v1/article/f0619b6a-738e-4470-897f-4e5cdad3ea52-1 "
          },
          "1": {
            "image": null,
            "title": "₹1,000, ₹5,000 and ₹10,000 notes were demonetised in 1978 ",
            "time": "10:20 pm ",
            "date": "08 Nov ",
            "content": "The Indian government had demonetised the ₹1,000, ₹5,000 and ₹10,000 currency notes in 1978 ...",
            "link": null
          },
          ...

        };

        // create a JSON object to handle the response JSON
        JSONObject yourJSONObject = new JSONObject(yourJSON);

        /*
        *this converts entire JSON object to JSON array since there is no further nesting
        *this can be placed in a loop and the 0 replaced by an incremental variable say "int i"
        */
        JSONArray data = yourJSONObject.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(0));

        // loop through the items in the first JSON array which in this case is only one therefore at index 0
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            // create JSON object to hold each item in array
            JSONObject json = null;

            try {
                //Getting json
                json = data.getJSONObject(i);

                String image = json.getString("image");
                String title = json.getString("title");
                String time = json.getString("time");
                String date = json.getString("date");
                String content = json.getString("content");
                String link = json.getString("link");

                // perform action on this specific item


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does `getJSONArray(0)` compile?

Comment: According to the documentation, that method doesn't exist. There are no arrays in that JSON, anyways

Comment: It does compile since this is an extract of code from one of my working Android projects

Comment: The method signature is `getJSONArray(String name)`, though, not an Integer... As I said, though, there isn't any array in that JSON

Comment: make sure it is String. Sorry for the misslead. Make it **"0"** or if you are using an incremental variable say **int i** then do **0+""+i**

Comment: @cricket_007 true, as I stated, this will be useful when the response from the server has more levels than what is shown here. Read the comments. Therefore this fix will work in this case and also modifiable for more complex applications

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your post. That still shouldn't work, for the reason I've already explained. It isn't `"0": [` in the data.

Comment: For incremental variables, use **""+i** not **0+""+i**

Comment: Thanks, but I already understand how to parse the data. The link in the first comment posted on the question works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ...

Try something like this ... just give you an idea ...

```
MyObject myObject = null;
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
try{
    myObject = new MyObject();
    int position = 0;
    while(position < 100){
        JSONObject jsonObject = object.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(position));
        String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
        myObject.setTitle(title);

        ...


        position++;
    }
}catch (JSONException e){
    return e.getMessage();
}finally{
    return myObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way i had same json response and it work for me

```
class LoadAllStates extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String test;
    private ArrayList<String> statedata;
    private ArrayList<String> idadddata;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShippingAddress.this.getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        statedata = new ArrayList<String>();

        idadddata = new ArrayList<String>();


        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(GET_ADDRESS_DETAIL, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 1; i <= jsonObj.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject user = jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i);


                    idaddress=String.valueOf(i);
                    System.out.println("userr"+i);

                    username= (user.has("name")) ? user.getString("name") : null;
                    usermobile= (user.has("mobile_number")) ? user.getString("mobile_number") : null;
                    useraddress= (user.has("address")) ? user.getString("address") : null;
                    userlandmark= (user.has("landmark")) ? user.getString("landmark") : null;
                    usercity= (user.has("city")) ? user.getString("city") : null;
                    userstate= (user.has("state")) ? user.getString("state") : null;
                    userpincode= (user.has("pin_code")) ? user.getString("pin_code") : null;
                    useremail= (user.has("email")) ? user.getString("email") : null;
                    if(username!=null)
                        statedata.add(username+","+usermobile+","+useraddress+","+userlandmark+","+usercity+","+userstate+","+userpincode+","+useremail);

                    idadddata.add(idaddress);
                    Log.i("inner",user.toString());
                }
                System.out.println("WifeBday"+statedata.size());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return statedata;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```