# how to fetch tags from wordpress posts JSON results in android Java

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress

I am trying to make an android app that fetch posts from my wordpress blog that displays the information in a list. I am able to get the results like title, description,etc but i am not able to get nested object "tags" from the JSON result. So, can you explain me how i can get the tag names from the JSON result from this [JSON Response](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/geekygamersclub.wordpress.com/posts/?number=2&pretty=true).

I am trying to use the following code :

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(postJSON);
        JSONArray postsArray = root.getJSONArray("posts");


        for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
            // Get a single post at position i within the list of earthquakes
            JSONObject currentPost = postsArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = currentPost.getString("title");
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "title is " + title);

            JSONObject tags = currentPost.getJSONArray("tags").getJSONObject(0);
            String tag = tags.getString("name");
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "tag is " + tag);

            Post post = new Post(title,"123", tag);
            posts.add(post);
        }
```

But the logcat is showing that the value can't be converted to JSONArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that tags is actually another JSON object not a JSON array. You need to do the following:

```
JSONObject tags = currentPost.getJSONObject("tags").getJSONObject(0);
String tag = tags.getString("name");
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "tag is " + tag);
```

Just remember JSON arrays are always denoted by [] and objects by {}.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right, BUT now the problem is that you can't use int as an input for JSONObject.

Comment: Ah, this question may help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606572/android-json-parsing-of-multiple-jsonobjects-inside-jsonobject