# How to get key values from json object in retrofit 2.3

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to parse the `json` object to get the dynamic keys and values and set them to `RecyclerView` in my application. And also I want to get the key or value when user clicks the `recyclerview` child.

```
{
"status": 200,
"message_type": "info",
    "car_types": {
        "sports_car": "BMW", 
        "sports_car": "lamborghini",
        "classic_car": "benz",
        "luxary_car": "bently cooper",
        "suv": "Range Rover",
        "Other": "Other"
    }
}
```

Comment: try this link : jsonschema2pojo

Comment: You mean your key will change dynamic .,i am correct.@Krishna Ch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606572/android-json-parsing-of-multiple-jsonobjects-inside-jsonobject refer this.

Comment: @Gowthaman Yes, the key will change and also the value will also change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following,To get key and value from the `JSONObject`.

```
   try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your result");

                JSONObject jsonObject1_message = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message_type");

                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                Iterator iter = jsonObject1_message.keys();

                while(iter.hasNext()){
                    String key = (String)iter.next();
                    String value = jsonObject1_message.getString(key);
                    map.put(key,value);

                    Log.d("keywithvalues","print    "+key+"   "+value);

                }



            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                        Log.d("error","**   "+e.toString());
            }
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: @Krishna Ch Try this let me know.

Comment: Sure, I will try it. Thank you for you response, I will let you know if it works :)

Comment: @KrishnaCh hey have you checked this,if it's working Please mark as accept ans as well as upvote.