# Get all value in JSONObject android

Tags: android, json

I have a JSONObject like this

```
{
"status": "fails",
"validation": {
"a": [
  "fd",
  "message 1"
],
"aa": [
  "2",
  "Message 2"
],
"aaa": [
  "2",
  "Message 3"
],
"afda": [
  "2",
  "Message 4"
],
"ada": [
  "2",
  "Message 2"
],
"aca": [
  "2",
  "Message 5"
]
},
"debug": "",
"data": null
}
```

Because the JSONObject in my project is dynamic.
So, is it possible to get all values in this JSONObject regardless the keys?

For example: My desire result is an array of string:
["message 1","message 2","message 3","message 4","message 5"]

Comment: This will be of help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a

Cheers!

Comment: Try Gson for json parsing ,this is easy and fast than json parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Example it is use full

[android_json_parser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

And This

[android-json-parsing-tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)