# How to parse JSONObject with other JSONObjects inside it?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a question about getting jsonobjects out of a jsonobject.

This is what im getting back:

```
{
"data": {
    "someid": {
        "air_by_date": 0, 
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1, 
            "poster": 1
        }, 
        "language": "en", 
        "network": "somenetwork", 
        "next_ep_airdate": "somedate", 
        "paused": 0, 
        "quality": "somequality", 
        "show_name": "somename", 
        "status": "Continuing", 
        "tvdbid": someid, 
        "tvrage_id": someid, 
        "tvrage_name": "Showname"
    }, 
    "someid": {
        "air_by_date": 0, 
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1, 
            "poster": 1
        }, 
        "language": "en", 
        "network": "somenetwork", 
        "next_ep_airdate": "", 
        "paused": 0, 
        "quality": "somequality", 
        "show_name": "somename", 
        "status": "Continuing", 
        "tvdbid": someid, 
        "tvrage_id": someid, 
        "tvrage_name": "somename"
    },
```

But how am i supposed to create "ShowObjects" of them. I know how it works with JSONArrays but i have never done this kind of JSON before.

This is what i got untill now:

```
String json = download(url);

JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject resultData = result.getJSONObject("data");
```

Comment: Are you wanting to loop through those numeric entries inside `data` and turn each of those into a `JSONObject`? If Yes, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13573965/802469) will help.

Comment: What you have should work just fine. What happens / does not work?

Comment: @jakar  Those numeric objects are representing a show, but how do i   loop through it? Because its not an JSONArray i get returned, im a little confused on how to do it.

Comment: @Timmeeh93: That is not JSON string you got over there.

Comment: do you want to create your own array of objects or fetch a specific object (someid)

Comment: that is not a valid json object. the same key is present twice.

Comment: (if you want a jsonarray, take a look at `JSONObject.names()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573965/802469):

Use the keys() iterator to iterate over all the properties, and call get() for each.

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still dont get it on how to create my own show object out of this.

Comment: If speed is a priority, then I would recommend just manually setting values of your `Show` object. ex: `show.setLanguage(showJson.getString('language'))`; Alternatively, you can use reflection to set property values based on the keys from the JSON where the JSON key = property name. This will negatively impact performance, though. If you want, i can update with a basic example for reflection

Comment: Or you can use a third-party json library that already handles that sort of thing. See the answer by Drejc

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for these tasks.

With [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) you would do something like this:

```
class Response() {
     public String message;
     public String result;
     public Map<String, Object> data; 
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
Resonse respone = mapper.readValue(json, Response.class)
```

or use a custom deserializer to read those values out.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example how to fetch the objects and vars in your "data" json:

lets say the second "someid" is : "123". We will fetch the second jsonObject now :

```
JSONObject secondJsonSomeId = resultData.getJsonObject("123");
```

Now we will fetch the "banner" ( int =1 ) of the jsonObject named "cache" located in our secondJsonSomeId  :

```
int bannerInsecondJsonSomeId = secondJsonSomeId.getJsonObject("cache").getInt("banner");// bannerInsecondJsonSomeId == 1
```

the code is not compiled so there might be errors , ask if you have additional questions.