# How Read JSON Array, Android Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I need to read this JSON array :

```
[{
"1":{"id":"0","name":"first"},
"2":{"id":"1","name":"second"}
}]
```

I use this code

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("Data: " + jsonObject.getString("id"));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            Log.e("Get Data from JSON Array ..", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But the array length = 1 always 
and the error appear : no value for id

The method to return JSON Array ..

```
    public static JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url)
{
    String str = "{\"Array\":["; // I add it because the JSON return from the site not contains root ..
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("url);        
    try 
    {
        response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
        str += EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "iso-8859-1") + "]}";
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("Client Protocol Exception", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IO Exception", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    JSONObject obj = null;
    JSONArray array = null;

    try  {
        obj = new JSONObject(str);
        array = obj.getJSONArray("Array");
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Exception", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return array;
}
```

How to solve it or how to read the JSON text ..

Thanks ,,

Comment: share how you instantiated array

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to create a class like this one:

```
public class ExampleClass { 
    int id; 
    String name; 
}
```

And then you call it in your try:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ExampleClass>>() { }.getType(); 
ArrayList<ExampleClass> arrayInJSON = gson.fromJson(exampleJSONObject, listOfTestObject);
```

Then, you can use the response from JSON to get the size:

```
arrayInJSON.size();
```

Comment: Thanks but it hard .. from my code I get the json array, but how to get the size without this method, any another method !!!

Comment: But is only copy first block of code and put outside of onCreate method and take the second block and put it in your try, below "jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);". Use the "jsonObject" here: ArrayList<ExampleClass> arrayInJSON = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, listOfTestObject);

Answer (score 0):

It is an array with one element on it
     [{
     "1":{"id":"0","name":"first"}, 
     "2":{"id":"1","name":"second"}
     }]

```
  becouse it look like [{...}] 

  here {...} is a map of 2 elements it is not array 
  jsonObject.getString("1").getString("id") in your code should return     what you need
```

Comment: Thanks :)
How I can know count the elements ??

Comment: I can not use .getString("1").getString("id")
So I create second json object 
jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
json = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("1"));
json.getString("id");

Comment: yes i can not sorry.  optJSONObject("1").getString("id")

Comment: iterate by key http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a