# Poorly formatted json parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

I use code above to parse `JSON` in a `try-catch`.

```
        JSONArray jsonRootObject = new JSONArray(text);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray(2);

        name = jsonArray.toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I use 2 as index in code below, because I would get values from candidates. I think, that is strange, because there isn't key-value pairs in array. I would like to get only the first key from this array (In this example `subtest1`.), its value isn't make sense.

```
{
    "images": [
    {
        "time": 2.86091,
        "transaction":
        {
            "status": "Complete",
            "subject": "test2",
            "confidence": 0.77,
            "gallery_name": "gallerytest1",
        },
        "candidates": [
        {
          "subtest1": "0.802138030529022",
          "enrollment_timestamp": "1416850761"
        },
        {
          "elizabeth": "0.802138030529022",
          "enrollment_timestamp": "1417207485"
        },
        {
          "elizabeth": "0.777253568172455",
          "enrollment_timestamp": "1416518415"
        },
        {
          "elizabeth": "0.777253568172455",
          "enrollment_timestamp": "1416431816"
        }
        ]
    } ]
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? your question is quit clear. make it clear first

Comment: You seem to confuse Json Arrays and Objects. In Objects you access the properties by name, in Arrays you access the elements by number.

Comment: What you want from your candidates array? The first element only?

Comment: @ShafayatMamun: Yes, exactly!

Comment: Ok then see my answer or ravi's answer. It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it solves your problem

```
 JSONArray CandidatesArr = new JSONArray(jsonRootObject.getString("candidates"));
        JSONObject CandidatesOBJ = CandidatesArr.getJSONObject(0);
String name=CandidatesOBJ.getString("subtest1");
```

**Edit**

To check if your key subset1 exists or not try the following code:

```
String name=""
    if(CandidatesOBJ.has("subtest1")){
name=CandidatesOBJ.getString("subtest1");
    }
```

Comment: I cannot say. that I need `subtest1`, because it is vary on request. So, it isn't fix value. In fact I would like to get `subtest1` as the value, because I can't know it in a response.

Comment: So you want to check if subset1 exists in your object and get the value of subset1? Or you want subset1 as the value? like the name of the keys(subset1/elizabeth) ?

Comment: See this answer [link]("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a")

Comment: I would like to check, if like subset1 is exists or not.

Comment: Updated my code. Please check if this was the thing that you were looking for.

Comment: It says: `org.json.JSONException: No value for candidates`

Answer (score 1):

your parser should be like.FYI JSONArray does not have key-value pairs but JSONObject does.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(text);
JSONArray jarray = root.optJSONArray("images);
if(jarray != null){
   JSONObject jObject = jarray.optJSONObject(0);
   if(jObject != null){
      JSONArray candidates = jObject.optJSONArray("candidates");
      JSONObject jObj = jarray.optJSONObject(0);
      if(jObj != null){
          String subTest =  jObj.optString("subtest1");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Same thing... I cannot say. that I need `subtest1`, because it is vary on request, this is not a fix name.

Comment: jobj.keys() you wil all the keys in the first jsonObject.You can loop for all the json Objects in jsonarray.

Comment: `subTest` string is also empty. I have tried to use my string instead of subtest1.