# Retrofit to parse json with an indefinite number of object names

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to handle rest-api calls.
I have a rest API that returns the following json

```
    "MyObject": {
      "43508": {
        "field1": 4339,
        "field2": "val",
        "field3": 15,
        "field4": 586.78
      },
      "1010030": {
        "field1": 1339,
        "field2": "val212",
        "field3": 1,
        "field4": 86.78
      },...
    }
```

Please notice that the object `MyObject` contains objects with a name that is actually an id.
For all the other rest APIs I'm using retrofit without problems.
In this case it seems not possible to use the standard approach: defining a class containing the fields expected in the response.

Is there a way to transform this json into a json containing an array of

```
{
    "field1": xxx,
    "field2": "yyy",
    "field3": www,
    "field4": zzz
}
```

Or is there a better way to deal with this problem without going back to "manually" parsing the json?

Comment: Very good question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use next approach:

```
public class Response {

    Map<String, YourObject> MyObject;
    // getter, setter
}

public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("some_path")
  Call<Response> listMyObjects();
}
```

All you objects will be parsed to Map. You can get the list of all ids via `keySet()` method or list all entries with `entrySet()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the annotation, SerializedName(nameOfField) over the variable name.

```
@SerializedName("13445345")
MyObject object;
```

Comment: the problem is that there is a huge number of possible ids. I can't set the SerializedName like that

Answer (score 0):

Well my idea is quite manual, but it should work. I will not copy and paste another person's answer here, so take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573965/5647037) to see how to loop through all of the `myObject`'s keys. Then for each of those keys, make a new `JSONArray` and add key value pair of `fieldX-valueX`.

This is just a basic idea, since I think you can handle the code yourself, you seem like a guy who knows his way around the simple stuff.