# How to handle JSON objects wrapped into one JSON object with retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I want to receive items using retrofit and parse them into a Java list.
However, the server response is not a JSON array but a JSON object containing the items. That is why retrofit cannot just convert the response into a java list.

The response looks something like this:

```
{
    "4": {
        "key": "value",
        ...
    },
    "5": {
        ...
    }, 
    ...
}
```

Usually, I would try to receive the items like this:

```java
@GET("items")
Call<List<Item>> getItems();
```

But this obviously does not work and Retrofit responds: `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`

What is my best option to convert this object into a java list using retrofit?

Comment: I faced this case once, I believe there is no way that Retrofit can fully parse the response like this, we have to catch the root object -> use GSon to convert it to String, then parse it manually.
The best way: tell server guy to fix it, he did a very bad and stupid thing!

Comment: I thin the solution could be someting like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550388/retrofit-to-parser-json-with-an-indefinite-number-of-object-names
Maybe something like Call<List<Map<String, Item>>>.
Try a bit arround, good luck.

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce Thank you for the answer. I am pretty sure that the server guys at Philips will not change this. But hopefully, they will not create something like this again.

Comment: @DanielSpiess: Thank you for the link. It is similar to Fred's answer and it solves my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally do this in 2 steps to avoid having to write a custom adapter for the deserialization.

I'd write the interface like:

```
@GET("items")
Call<Map<String, Item>> getItems();
```

And once you'd call the API on the response I'd just call `values()`.

Things to take into consideration is that because the API returns a map and not a list, there's no guarantee that the order of any list you'd produce would be consistent. The json standard doesn't define any order for objects unless they're in a json array.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the response is List, the JSON should be an "ARRAY".

E.g.:

```
[ "a", "b" ]
```

or

```
{ 
   "xxx": [ "a", "b" ] 
}
```

In either case, the objects you'd want to parse into would look like:

`List<String>` for the first one.

`Thing` for the second one.

And `Thing` would look like:

```
class Thing {
   public List<String> xxx;
}
```

You're trying to parse this:

```
{
    "4": {
        "key": "value",
        ...
    },
    "5": {
        ...
    }, 
    ...
}
```

So based on the above information, what do you think your response looks like when parsed? (hint: you can try something like [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) Java POJO generator to get an idea ;)

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I cannot change the server response. That is why I have to deal with this stupid 'object-list'.

Comment: Gotcha, I see you've already gotten an answer. I was simply teasing you to see if you could figure it out on your own (it's just a Map<> not a List<>) but glad to hear you've solved it ;)