# How to get key from json object

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have the json array :

```
{"objets":{"1":"Question","2":"Response"},"success":true}
```

I want to test if the text selected on spinner exist in the array it will return the number (1 or 2).

Here is what I've done until now :

```
String responseContent = response.asString();
                                    Log.d("OBJECTS", responseContent);
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(responseContent);
                                        JSONObject users = jobj.getJSONObject("objetcs");
                                        Log.e("hello", String.valueOf(users));

                                        if(users.toString().contains(spinner_objet.getSelectedItem().toString().trim())){
                                            Log.e("hello", "it exist");
                                            String user=users.getString("id");
                                            Log.e("hello1", String.valueOf(user));
                                        }


                                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

But I'm not getting any thing, can any one help me with this ?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: That is not a json Array.

Comment: @P.Juni I don't get anything

Comment: Your question is not clear. First of all code you posted is a JsonObject. What kind of array you are talking about?

Comment: could you provide full json structure ?

Comment: Can you see the update ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android (JSONObject) How can I loop through a flat JSON object to get each key and each value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a)

Comment: **I'm not getting the Can any thing** ... Ok then...

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your Json into a hashMap like so :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
while (object.keys().hasNext() ){
    Integer key = (Integer) object.keys().next();
    map.put((String) object.get(String.valueOf(key)), key);
}
```

You can then use the values of the map to put in the spinner.

```
map.values();
```

Whenever the user selects from the spinner, you can get the id from the map.