# JSONArray recognized as JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays, json

I jave a JSONArray "appelliLista" that get recognized as JSONObject. So i cant loop to retrieve data for each record.

```
                   //Recovering data object 
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject disponibiliì = obj.getJSONObject("result");

                    JSONArray lista = disponibiliì.getJSONArray("appelliLista"); //not working
                    JSONObject  lista2 = disponibiliì.getJSONObject("appelliLista"); //working in the wrong way no error but just cant loop
```

JSON RESPONSE

`

```
{
"service": "appelliLista",
"status-code": 200,
"status-description": "success",
"time-spent": 0.116739,
"server-time": "07/05/2019-04:03:57pm",
"result": {
"appelliLista": {
1: {
"Attivita didattica": "SISTEMI OPERATIVI",
"Appello": "22/05/2019",
"Iscrizione": "07/05/201920/05/2019",
"Descrizione": "SISTEMI OPERATIVI",
"Sessioni": "2018/2019",
"link": "APP_ID=62&CDS_ESA_ID=10047&ATT_DID_ESA_ID=5868&ADSCE_ID=20148812&AA_OFF_ID=2014&CDS_ID=10047&PDS_ID=9999&AA_ORD_ID=2013&ISCR_APERTA=1&TIPO_ATTIVITA=1&TIPO_APP_COD=0"
}
}
}
}
```

`

Comment: check your api/web service

Comment: Your json array is wrong see in https://jsonlint.com/ and validate json

Comment: according to jsonResponse there is no JSONArray, so the code is right. You need to check up with your webservice.

Comment: its ok, `appelliLista` is an object, not array: `"appelliLista": {` - note it starts with `{` - for more see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types_and_syntax

Comment: can u show how should be the right format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: JSONArray is using [], not {}

Comment: If you would still like to loop through your "appelliLista" JSON object, you can use an [Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a/54509189).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json array format is

```
"appelliLista":[
  {....},
  {....}
]
```

your json element appelliLista is a json object so cannot parse to array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON object is like below, you can simply iterate over it this way:

```js
        var object = {
            "service": "appelliLista",
                "status-code": 200,
                    "status-description": "success",
                        "time-spent": 0.116739,
                            "server-time": "07/05/2019-04:03:57pm",
                                "result": {
                                            "appelliLista": {
                                                1: {
                                                    "Attivita didattica": "SISTEMI OPERATIVI",
                                                        "Appello": "22/05/2019",
                                                            "Iscrizione": "07/05/201920/05/2019",
                                                                "Descrizione": "SISTEMI OPERATIVI",
                                                                    "Sessioni": "2018/2019",
                                                                        "link": "APP_ID=62&CDS_ESA_ID=10047&ATT_DID_ESA_ID=5868&ADSCE_ID=20148812&AA_OFF_ID=2014&CDS_ID=10047&PDS_ID=9999&AA_ORD_ID=2013&ISCR_APERTA=1&TIPO_ATTIVITA=1&TIPO_APP_COD=0"
                                                }
                                            }
            }
        }




        for (key in object) {
            console.log(key + " : " + object[key]);
        }
```

Comment: the language is java not javascript. can you show me how to iterate in java?

Comment: I see, you check this link, maybe it help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject