# JSONObject to JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need some help here. I am still new in android developer.

Here is example of the data

```
strAPI_TERMINAL= "{ 'terminal': { 'id': 2, 'fmt_id': 'fmt0002', 'terminal_type': 'multiple' }}"
```

I need to parse this object data to JSONArray

Here what i ve done...

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strAPI_TERMINAL);
JSONArray terminal_array = new JSONArray();
JSONArray t_array = terminal_array.put(jsonObject);
```

When I Log out the data...yes it has been parse to array just like this

`t_array[{"terminal":{"fmt_id":"fmt0002","id":2,"terminal_type":"multiple"}]`

But When I wanna use it to get the "terminal" data using this...

```
JSONArray TERMINAL_JSON=new JSONArray(t_array.getJSONObject(i).getString("terminal").toString());
```

It says:

```
Error:Value {"id":2,"fmt_id":"fmt0002","terminal_type":"multiple"}
```

Anyone please help me???

thanks for any help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try out parse JSON as below:

> ```
> JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(strAPI_TERMINAL);
>  try {
>   JSONArray result = obj1.getJSONArray("terminal");
> for(int i=0;i<=result.length();i++)
>  {
>     String Id=result.getString("fmt_id");
>       String terminalType=result.getString("terminal_type");
>  }
>  } catch (JSONException e) {
>      e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: a little correction: result.length() length - is a method name in this case

Answer (score 2):

As Josnidhin said, 'terminal' is a JSON Object.  If you want it to be an array, you need to make it so in the first place (notice the array brackets):

```
strAPI_TERMINAL= "{ 'terminal': [{ 'id': 2, 'fmt_id': 'fmt0002', 'terminal_type': 'multiple' }]}"
```

Are you really just trying to iterate through the keys in the terminal object?  If so, maybe you would want to check out this post:  [How to iterate over a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code't_array' is an array of JSONObject. To access each item in 't_array' you will need to get each item as JSONObject and then access the values of that JSONObject.

The value of 'terminal' is a json object you cant convert it to json array just like that.

To access the value of 'terminal' do something like the following

```
t_array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("terminal");
```

The above code will return the following as JSONObject

```
{ 'id': 2, 'fmt_id': 'fmt0002', 'terminal_type': 'multiple' }
```

Comment: Yes...but when i doing for loop it repeated..because i cannot take the index of the data...not like JSONArray..i can use index to get the exact data...any idea?

Comment: And also...the terminal is already parse to Array if you see the log t_array[{"terminal":{"fmt_id":"fmt0002","id":2,"terminal_type":"multiple"}]...but i am not sure it is really converted or not...

Comment: Terminal was not parsed to array it was added to an array. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry...if i ve done it in object, can i get the index of each object in for loop?