# JSONObject to Document

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Hi there i am new with mongodb and i want to convert JSONObject to Document and then store it to mongodb.
Here is what i have  coded.I get a service api in json.

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();          
        JSONObject Rat = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

then i want to save this Rat to a mongodb as a document and then insert it to mongodb or to mysql so that i can display it later.
I thought something like

```
Document  doc = new Document(....);
coll.insertOne(doc); /*where coll is 
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("rates"); */
```

but how to do the convertion from JSONObject to Document?

Comment: i have read this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282181/how-do-i-convert-a-jsonobject-to-class-object) this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501758/jsonobject-to-jsonarray)  and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject)

Comment: I also want to get some values from the Rat . I have already done this. But still thinking how to save JSONObject to mogno only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help you. You can also do:

```
JSONObject rat = exRat.getJSONObject("fieldfromJson");String newrat = rat.toString();
```

Then you have to parse the field you want, and you have a string.

Answer (score 20):

The MongoDB Java Driver provides the `Document.parse(String json)` method to get a Document instance from a JSON string.  You will need to parse your JSON object back to a String like this:

```
Document doc = Document.parse( Rat.toString() );
```

And here's the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/bson/extended-json/) for working with JSON in the MongoDB Java Driver.