# How do I get the key for each object in a dynamic JSON array?

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

How do I parse this object and get the name (key) for each person?

I can't just do `String name = jsonObject.getString("name");` because the name is the *key*, not the value.

JSONObject **jsonObject** =

```
{
    "data" :
    [{
        "Bob": {
            "last-name": "Jorgenson",
            "email": "b@b.com",
        },

        "Steve": {
            "last-name": "Bobson",
            "email": "steve@juno.com",
        },
    }],
    "statusCode" : 200
}
```

So what's the best way to parse it with the dynamically-named keys?

#### Update:

jArray was taken from the jsonObject which is now represented. However, I was having trouble implementing answers because of type errors related to trying to get jArray from `jsonObject.get("data")`

#### Disclaimer

Yes, this is pretty basic stuff. The dynamic bit is throwing me off though. There are many similar questions, but they usual involve a number of other factors. I can successfully download the data and store it in the JSONObject **jsonObject** above. I just need to figure out how to parse the data as outlined above.

Comment: `JSONObject` should have a `keys` method or something similar. Just iterate over the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java iterate over JSONObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
    }
```

Comment: Beautifully succinct answer.
Does the iterator skip item[0] because it starts with keys.next()?

When I log key at each part of the while loop, it only Logs n-1 of the elements in the data (indicating it may be skipping an item at the beginning or the end.)

Comment: That's odd. Iterators always starts *before* the first item. Maybe you should post that as a new question...

Comment: I'll double check and make sure I didn't mess anything up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `keys()` method of JSONObject might be the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name;
    Iterator<String> keys = temp.keys();
    if(keys.hasNext())
        name = keys.next();
}
```