# Parse json(android)

Tags: android, json

Before I parse json `json array`, but this json object. Its It drove me to a standstill. How i can parse json like this:

```
 { "test1": {
            "1": {
                "action": "0",
                "type": "1",
                "id": "1",
            },
            "2": {
                "action": "0",
                "type": "1",
                "id": "2",
            }
        },
        "test2": {
            "1": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "one"
            },
            "2": {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "two"
            },
            "5": {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "three"
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Explain your problem?

Comment: your json is not correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java iterate over JSONObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JSONObject From string as bellow

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
```

and to parse the `jsonObject`

```
JSONObject test1Json = jsonObject.getJSONObject("test1");
JSONObject oneTest1Json = test1Json.getJSONObject("1");
```

to get String values

```
String action = oneTest1Json.getString("action");
String type = oneTest1Json.getString("type");
String id = oneTest1Json.getString("id");
Log.d("Json parse","action -"+action+" type -"+type+" id -"+id);
```

if need them as `JSONArray` the you can try

```
public JSONArray getJsonArray (JSONObject jsonObject){
    JSONArray nameJsonArray = jsonObject.names();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < nameJsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            String key = nameJsonArray.getString(i);
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject.getString(key));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

in case keys like test1,test2,test3...

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{'test1':'Kasun', 'test2':'columbo','test3': '29'}");
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 1; i <= jsonObject.names().length(); i++) {
        try{
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject.getString("test" + i));
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

you can get your `JSONArray` this way.

Comment: thanks for answer, but if i have dynamicly `test`, example `test1`, `test2` ...`test34`

Comment: welcome,you can use a for loop for that,i made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't have a fixed set of keys, that you know upfront, the only way to parse it is to use `keys()`. It returns an `Iterator` with the keys contained in the `JSONObject`. In your case you could have

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(...);
Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  String currentKey = iterator.next();
  JSONObject obj = jsonObject.optJSONObject(key); 
  if (obj != null) {
     Iterator<String> iterator2 = obj.keys();

  }
}
```

`iterator` will return `test1` and `test2`, while `iterator2` will return `1` and `2`, for `test1` and `1` ,`2` , `5` for `test2`