# How to read all keys in Json without specifying keyname using java

Tags: java, json

Trying to read Json Message like below

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Jones"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to read all keynames like employees,firstName,lastName etc.. in java.
in XML we do this while parsing we specify * in dom object and get all node names, how to do this in java?

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Use [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) library.

Example:

```
import org.json.*;

String myJSONString =  // put here your json object
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
// get all the keys
String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(object);

// iterate over them
for (String key : keys)
{
    // retrieve the values
    Object value = object.get(key);
    // if you just have strings:
    String value = (String) object.get(key);

}
```

JAR: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: Getting below error when using the code "The method getNames(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONObject"

Answer (score 0):

This didnt seems to work anymore. However, [Rickey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711993/rickey) pointed out another solution using iterators, which is mostly a smarter idea to use anyways:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(contents.trim());
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
          // do something with jsonObject here      
    }
}
```

(Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10593838/7184809))