# GSON. How to convert json object to json array?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

Now I am getting this JSON from API:

```
{"supplyPrice": {
        "CAD": 78,
        "CHF": 54600.78,
        "USD": 20735.52
      }}
```

But prices are dynamic, that's why I need JSON in this form

```
{
  "supplyPrice": [
    {
      "name": "CAD",
      "value": "78"
    },
    {
      "name": "TRY",
      "value": "34961.94"
    },
    {
      "name": "CHF",
      "value": "54600.78"
    },
    {
      "name": "USD",
      "value": "20735.52"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to do this using GSON?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you might receive a JsonObject or a JsonArray. You can call getAsJsonObject() method, and it that fails, call getAsJsonArray().

Comment: Or use isJsonObject() method, and depending of the result, call getAsJsonObject() or getAsJsonArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rohit Patil! I modified his code to my situation and it works!

```
private JSONObject modifyPrices(JSONObject JSONObj) {
    try {
        JSONObject supplyPrice = JSONObj.getJSONObject("supplyPrice");
        JSONArray supplyPriceArray = new JSONArray();
        Iterator<?> keys = supplyPrice.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            String value = supplyPrice.getString(key);
            supplyPriceArray.put(new JSONObject("{\"name\":" + key + ",\"value\":" + value + "}"));
        }
        JSONObj.put("supplyPrice", supplyPriceArray);
        return JSONObj;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this part of code to help you:

```
    String json = "{\"supplyPrice\": {\n" +
            "        \"CAD\": 78,\n" +
            "        \"CHF\": 54600.78,\n" +
            "        \"USD\": 20735.52\n" +
            "      }}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
    JsonObject supplyPrice = jsonObject.get("supplyPrice").getAsJsonObject();
    Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Double>>() {
    }.getType();
    HashMap<String, Double> parsedJson = gson.fromJson(supplyPrice, type);
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    for(String key : parsedJson.keySet()) {
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        jo.addProperty("name", key);
        jo.addProperty("value", parsedJson.get(key));
        jsonArray.add(jo);
    }
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    result.add("supplyPrice", jsonArray.getAsJsonArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

GSON uses POJO classes to parse JSON into java objects.

Create A java class containing variables with names and datatype same as keys of JSON object. I think the JSON you are getting is not in the right format.

```
Class SupplyPrice{
 double CAD;
 double CHF;
 double TRY
}

Class SupplyPriceContainer{
 ArrayList<SupplyPrice> supplyPrice;
}
```

And your JSON should be

```
 {
    "CAD": 78,
    "CHF": 54600.78,
    "USD": 20735.52
 }



{
    "supplyPrice": [{
        "CAD": 78,
        "CHF": 0,
        "USD": 0
    }, {
        "CAD": 0,
        "CHF": 54600.00,
        "USD": 0
    }, {
        "CAD": 0,
        "CHF": 0,
        "USD": 20735.52
    }]
 }
```

Then you can Use GSON's `fromJson(String pJson, Class pClassType) to convert to JAVA object

```
  Gson gson = new Gson()
  ArrayList<SupplyPrice> suplyPrices = gson.fromJson(pJsonString, SupplyPrice.class);
```

Now you can use the arraylist to get the data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate all keys of supplyPrice object, and create New JSONArray using that key value then assign new array to supplyPrice key

```
JSONObject changeSupplyPrice(JSONObject JSONObj){
    try {
        JSONObject supplyPrice =JSONObj.getJSONObject("supplyPrice");
        JSONArray supplyPriceArray = new JSONArray();
        Iterator<?> keys = supplyPrice.keys();

        while( keys.hasNext() ) {
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            Log.e("JSON Array key",key);
            supplyPriceArray.put(new JSONObject("{"+key+":"+supplyPrice.getString(key)+"}"));

        }
        JSONObj.put("supplyPrice", supplyPriceArray);
        return JSONObj;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

then call the function where you want

```
try {
        JSONObject JSONObj = new JSONObject("{'taxes': [],'name': 'Laboriosam iusto eum','requiresShipping': false,  'taxable': true,  'sku': 'QBA84J18832',  'product': 12, 'supplyPrice': {    'CAD': 78,   'CHF': 54600.78,    'USD': 20735.52  }}");
        JSONObj = changeSupplyPrice(JSONObj);
        Log.e("Return JSON Object",JSONObj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert it to an `HashMap or TreeMap` then navigate your map for all the keys.

This will be simplest way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Once look at this.. may help you.

```
 JSONObject json= json.getJSONObject("supplyPrice");
    Iterator i = json.keys();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    while (i.hasNext()){
        String key = (String) i.next();
        jsonArray.put(json.get(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

We are only one line of code away from converting jsonObjects to arrays(Not jsonArrays but after making it a arrayList you can create jsonArray too,easily.)

```
fun <LIST_TYPE>jsonObjectToArray(jsonObject : JsonObject,listTypeClass : Class<LIST_TYPE>) = arrayListOf<LIST_TYPE>().apply { jsonObject.keySet().forEach { this.add(Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.get(it).toString(),listTypeClass))}}
```