# can't iterate over a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

[SOLVED]

```
private  void jsonObjectToMap(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Iterator iter = jsonObject.keys();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iter.next();
            JSONObject value = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
            Iterator iter2 = value.keys();
            while (iter2.hasNext()) {
                String key2 = (String) iter2.next();
                Object value2 = value.get(key2);
                map.put(key2,value.toString());
                System.out.println(key2 + " : " + value2);
            }
        }
```

i have the following JSON (see "json" below), using [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject), I always get `"1"` as `key` and `"{"this": 1, "is": 1,"an": 1, "example": 1,"text": 1}` as `value`. I would like to have each word in the brackets as separated `keys` and the associated numbers a `value`.

this the last code i tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonObject.names().length(); i++){
    System.out.println("key = " + jsonObject.names().getString(i) + 
            " value = " + jsonObject.get(jsonObject.names().getString(i)));
}
```

json:

```
"1": {
      "this": 1,
      "is": 1,
      "an": 1,
      "example": 1,
      "text": 1
     }
```

Whole JSON, but i isolated the json-object `"1"`

```
"output": {
           "status": 1,
           "result": {
                      "1": {
                             "this": 1,
                             "is": 1,
                             "an": 1,
                             "example": 1,
                             "text": 1
                           }
                      } 
           }
```

Comment: This isn't a JSON list, this is an object.  What would give you the impression that you should iterate over it?

Comment: Could you tell us where the JSONObject comes from ? It depends of this object.

Comment: This is behaving as expected. In your object, "1" is the key and the rest the value. What is the datatype of jsonObject? Try not to omit relevant code.

Comment: As could your question also include the complete JSON you're attempting to read?

Comment: @Makoto: i know that it is an JSON-Object, i am trying to find a way to iterate over it.

Comment: @PascalHeraud: i iam using an API which counts the usage of each word in a text.

Comment: @DanFarrell: i edit the whole JSON into the post, but i have isolated the Json-Object "1",