# Firebase REST API get all data from node as JSON Array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any possibility in Firebase to get data from node as JSON array, but not like multiple objects

For example I have:

```
https://additive-food-e2a9a.firebaseio.com/additive.json
{"-KjrTAOehl0RAvKYlYVp":{"alias":"Curcumin","danger":"2","name":"E100"},"-KjrUIm-itn8h8EjckNQ":{"alias":"Curcumin","danger":"2","name":"E100"},"-KjrXlvuJjMuogCJmGDK":{"alias":"Curcumin","danger":"2","name":"E100"}}
```

But I need something like:

```
[{"-KjrTAOehl0RAvKYlYVp":{"alias":"Curcumin","danger":"2","name":"E100"},"-KjrUIm-itn8h8EjckNQ":{"alias":"Curcumin","danger":"2","name":"E100"},"-KjrXlvuJjMuogCJmGDK":{"alias":"Curcumin","danger":"2","name":"E100"}]
```

Comment: Is the only thing that is different about what you want that you put `[]` around it? If so, it should be easy to add the result you get from Firebase to an array. But this reads very much like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, instead of the step of your solution where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase returns only JSON object when you hit GET request to the node. You have to apply JSON parsing logic in Java, Javascript or whatever language you use.
[Sample JSON Parsing logic in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject)