# bind different json to spinner

Tags: android, json, spinner

i have strange situation i am not getting idea how to bind this json response to spinner.
i implement this way but not getting success all value.please suggest or help me to bind it .

json response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "gujarati": "Gujarati",
            "english": "English",
            "hindi": "Hindi",
            "hebrew": "Hebrew",
            "french": "French",
            "spanish": "Spanish",
            "arabic": "Arabic",
            "polish": "Polish",
            "bulgarian": "Bulgarian",
            "dude": "Dude",
            "all of them": "All Of Them",
            "uk english": "Uk English"
        }
    ]
}
```

add to list by key.

```
try {
                    root = new JSONObject(resplanguage);
                    JSONArray contacts = root.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        languagelist.add(new LanguageData(c.getString("gujarati"), c.getString("english"), c.getString("hindi"),
                                c.getString("hebrew"), c.getString("french"), c.getString("spanish"), c.getString("arabic"),
                                c.getString("polish"), c.getString("bulgarian"), c.getString("dude"), c.getString("all of them"),
                                c.getString("uk english")));

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

bind to spinner.

```
for (int k=0;k<languagelist.size();k++){
                    englisins[k]= String.valueOf(languagelist.get(k));
                }
                englishadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(ExploreInstructorActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, englisins);
                englishadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spEnglishSpeaking.setAdapter(englishadapter);
```

Comment: you get the json data without problems, can you add the way that you use to get data.

Comment: Make sure that languagelist is the first index object of data array inside the outer JSON object and not the JSON object jnstead.

Comment: i am not success  to add all string@Brunoferreira

Comment: my list size is 1 @aakashverma

Comment: look my edited question @aakashverma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are again not accessing the JSON object inside the array. Try this and let me know:

```
    try {
                        root = new JSONObject(resplanguage);
                        JSONArray contacts = root.getJSONArray("data");
                        JSONObject obj = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
                        Iterator it = obj.keys();
                        while(it.hasNext() ) {                       
                            languagelist.add((String)obj.get(it.next()));
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```