# How to retrieve the parent key name from it's child key?

Tags: android, json

In this case, I want to retrieve the `m1` key by referring to it's child key with the value of `amoxicillin` from firebase. I haven't tried to code it because i don't know where to begin.

```
{
  "Medicines" : {
    "m1" : {
      "class" : "antibiotic",
      "name" : "amoxcillin"
    },
    "m2" : {
      "class" : "analgesic",
      "name" : "paracetamol"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array of medicines:

```
Medicine[] medicines
```

You could iterate over each object in it and check if the class is `amoxicillin` or not:

```
for (int i = 0; i < medicines.length; i++) {
    Medicine medicine = medicines[i];

    if (medicine.getClass().equals("amoxicillin")) {
        // do smth here.. add the medicine to a separate array
        // or do smth with the index
        // for your case you should iterate over the jsonObject
        // and catch the key here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question just now, i forgot adding the db structure

Comment: My answer is still more or less the same. Read the comments in the code. You need to iterate over the jsonObject and get the key when class matches

Comment: Uhmm the json is actually from firebase, i just can't add an image to illustrate clearly, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Have a field for the parent in the child class(Model) then ie

```
    parent : { 
           child : { 
                  ...
                  parent: "parent_key" 
                  ...
                   }
     }
```

Comment: I have edited my question just now, i forgot adding the db structure

Comment: {
  "Medicines" : {
    "m1" : {
      "class" : "antibiotic",
      "name" : "amoxcillin",
      "parent" : "m1"
    },
    "m2" : {
      "class" : "analgesic",
      "name" : "paracetamol",
      "parent" : "m2"