# How to parse JSON with multiple return types

Tags: java, json

I need to parse a JSON, that can be of any type.

The data returned can be much complicated but i just need to fetch the value string used in that JSON object or array

The example of the JSON data is

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json
```

What I have done so far is :

```
public class UrlActions {

     private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int cp; 
            while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
              sb.append((char) cp);
            }
            return sb.toString();
          }

          public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            try {
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
              String jsonText = readAll(rd);
              JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
              return json;
            } finally {
              is.close();
            }
          }

}
```

but cannot be the same thing as i want
Kindly please help me

Thanks
Regards

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i need all the values to be fetched like "name" : "USD/KRW",
"price" : "1072.229980",
"symbol" : "KRW=X",
"ts" : "1525199087",
"type" : "currency",
"utctime" : "2018-05-01T18:24:47+0000",
"volume" : "0"

Comment: OK; what's the problem?

Comment: the data i am getting returned i the whole json object i just need the values like USD/KRW or 1072.229980 etc just the values not the keys or json objects or json arrays

Comment: Look here maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject

Comment: You need to learn [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/1429387).

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: Do you really need to parse *any* JSON imaginable? Or do you want to extract specific data from a specific JSON object?

Comment: @LutzHorn i need to parse any JSON not specific data

Comment: Why? What will you do with the data if you don't know the structure and what it means?

Comment: @LutzHorn my idea is to just insert the api url and get all the result values and save it in spreadsheet so url can be different

Comment: JSON is not flat like a spreadsheet would be. How do you plan to map a complex, nested JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a class of the type of the objects in the json, then you can use libraries such as Jackson's ObjectMapper to read values, e.g.

```
List<Quote> quotes = objectMapper.readValue(yourjson, new TypeReference<List<Quote>>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a structure which have key and value both of type string, one can use the below code.

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"Shepherd\", \"age\":26}";
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// convert JSON string to Map
map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

Now you can do:

```
map.get(key) //Here map.get("name")
```

for whatever you want to retrieve.However in your case as pointed out in the previous answer you need to provide the suitable Type References.

NOTE: I am using jackson here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea what is in the JSON (so you can't parse it with a class), you can take [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) ([Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)). With that you can iterate JSON file by using JsonToken to know what is next.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(inputfile));

while (reader.hasNext()) {
  JsonToken currentToken = reader.peek();
  switch (currentToken) { 
    case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        // read "{"
        reader.beginObject();
        break;
    case END_OBJECT:
        // read "}"
        reader.endObject();
        break;
    case BEGIN_ARRAY:
        // read "["
        reader.beginArray();
        break;
    case END_ARRAY:
        // read "]"
        reader.endArray();
        break;
    case END_DOCUMENT:
        // end of document
        break;
    default:
        reader.nextName(); // that gives "key"
        // next gives "values"
        reader.nextNull();
        reader.nextString();
        reader.nextBoolean();
        // there others like nextLong(), nextInt() but i recommand you 
        // to check if JsonToken.NUMBER, take the value in string
        // then parse it in the numeric class you want
   }
}
```