# JAVA - json parser - keys() to parse unknown json format?

Tags: java, json

I try to parse a simple json dictionary, so I read many tutorials and threads on how to achieve this

but there is no "keys()" nor "keySet()" defined for JSONObject nor JSONArray

I downloaded the library here :

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple111jar.htm
```

I am starting to wonder if I use the right library

here is my code :

```
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(json.trim());
Iterator keys = obj.keys(); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< keys() undefined
while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
}
```

json example :

```
{a:132,b:"1321",test:"something"}
```

any help appreciated

thanks

Comment: You can use the `gson` library.

Comment: can you share sample json format?

Comment: I try to use org.json.JSONObject but I can't find it anywhere

Comment: honnestly, if anyone could help me parse json in java, I dont care which library, so far it's a complete mess

Comment: I think I found it http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgjsonjar.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject)

Comment: Please don't post answers in your question: post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
JSONObject jsonArray = ...//get json object

Iterator<?> keys = jsonArray.keys();

while( keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    System.out.println("Value: " + jsonArray.get(key));
    System.out.println("Key: " + key);
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in my question there is no .keys() method

Comment: In json-simple,https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java  JSONObject extends HashMap, so you should use keySet()... or change to use the json.org library instead

Comment: YES !!! it works using this library http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgjsonjar.htm

Comment: I had keySet undefined with simpleJSON

Answer (score 0):

I think `keySet().iterator()` is, what you need:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(json.trim());
    Iterator keys = obj.keySet().iterator();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following. You have a few problems I have outlined afterwards.

```
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaJson{
    public static void main(String ... args){
        try{
            String json = "{\"name\":\"TEST\"}"; //Or whatever
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(json.trim());
            Iterator itr = obj.keySet().iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                System.out.println((String)itr.next());
            }
        }
        catch(ParseException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Problems being,

- It is `Iterator itr = obj.keySet().iterator();` not `Iterator keys =
  obj.keys();`. `JSONObject` does not have a definition for `keys()`.
- Missing import `import java.util.*`. `Iterator` is available in there.
- Should either catch or throw `ParseException`.