# parsing a json file without knowing it structure using only java

Tags: java, json, dom

so I have, I doing a program that receives a string json with an unknown structure (since it's a variable each time I receive a new one) and it needs to parse the string to extract each key and its type (from its value).
I need to do this using only java (no spring) because I've seen solution using Jackson tree, but with the software I'm using it impossible
If someone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496485/13238310

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA - json parser - keys() to parse unknown json format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496322/java-json-parser-keys-to-parse-unknown-json-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONObject from org.json library .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).