# fetch json android data

Tags: android, json, fetch

How to fetch this data using json.Is it an object or an array? I am confused. Below is my data and what I have implemented. I am unable to get any values. Please help me to fetch the values.

```
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jobject.getJSONArray("variety");
    for (int i =0; i<=jsonArray.length();i++){
        jobject=  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        txt_today_671.setText(jobject.getString("variety.coc671"));
      }

     {
    "status": 200,
    "variety": {
        "coc671": {
            "today": 0,
            "todate": 0
        },
        "co92005": {
            "today": 0,
            "todate": 0
        },
     },
        "others": {
            "today": 0,
            "todate": 0
        }
    },
    "distance": {
        "0to20": {
            "today": 0,
            "todate": 0
        },
        "20to40": {
            "today": 0,
            "todate": 0
        },
    "above100": {
            "today": 0,
            "todate": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The json Object starts from {} and Array starts from [] , so look again now and tell what is it

Comment: @Shararti KAKI - All are objects

Comment: yes , now you can get what you want

Comment: @Shararti KAKI - Help me fetch the values..

Comment: Instead of `JSONArray jsonArray = jobject.getJSONArray("variety");`
you should fetch it like `JSONObject object = jobject.getJSONObject("variety");`

variety is `JSONObject` not `JSONArray` everything which is wrapped in {} is Object and everything which is wrapped in [] is an array.

And instead of looping you can iterate over an object. look at this answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/10593838/4985413

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar see this example  yout will get more idea about json parsing https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

Here, `variety` and `distance` is not jsonArray, it's a jsonObject.

To iterate through jsonObject follow below mechanism-

```
JSONObject varietyObject = jobject.getJSONObject("variety");
Iterator<JSONObject> keysVariety = varietyObject.keys();

while(keysVariety.hasNext()) {
String keyVariety = keysVariety.next();
    JSONObject objectVariety = varietyObject.getJSONObject(keyVariety);
    // here you will get inner String/int values
    int today = objectVariety.getInt("today");
    int todate = objectVariety.getInt("todate");
}
```

Do same for distance object-

```
JSONObject distanceObject = jobject.getJSONObject("distance");
Iterator<JSONObject> keysDistance = distanceObject.keys();

while(keysDistance.hasNext()) {
String keyDistance = keysDistance.next();
    JSONObject objectDistance = distanceObject.getJSONObject(keyDistance);
    // here you will get inner String/int values
    int today = objectDistance.getInt("today");
    int todate = objectDistance.getInt("todate");
}
```

**Always remember JSONArray starts with `[` and JSONObject start with `{`**

Comment: It should be Iterator<JSONObject> not Iterator<String>. Sorry for that mistake. Please check my updated answer and if it helps you to solve, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: @Exigente05 this should be comment not answer.

Comment: @ Exigente05 - im unable to fetch distance values

Comment: Check your json is valid or not -https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
I had ti change something to make it valid
Above code is working - https://ibb.co/B3nst77
There is little change in variable naming. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

to just illustrate you a little , here in the demo there could be typo mistakes,

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response); // here you are getting all your object in one object
JSONObject varityObject= jobject.getJSONObject("variety");
//NOW USE varityObject to get coc671 and  co92005
//Similarly 
JSONObject distanceObject= jobject.getJSONObject("distance");
// now use distanceObject to get its items
```