# set images in image in a loop with Picasso

Tags: android, json, android-imageview, picasso

I have a `.json` like so

```
 {
        "0": {

            "image_path": "192.168.1.52/test/image/im1.jpg",
            "title": "image 1"
        },
          "1": {

            "image_path": "192.168.1.52/test/image/im2.jpg",
            "title": "image 2"
        },
          "2": {

            "image_path": "192.168.1.52/test/image/im2.jpg",
            "title": "image 3"
        },
  "size": "3"
}
```

My android portion is...

```
 RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
int size =  Integer.parseInt(jObj.getString("size"));

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
              JSONObject jObj_ =  jObj.getJSONObject(""+i);
                        String image_path_variable = jObj_.getString("image_path");
      }
```

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to insert images dynamically using the path I have in my `.json` file.
so my layout will have multiple image view depending on what the for loop has example of there are 3 images the page will have 3 images
 what i am saying the my json wont always have 3 images sometimes it will have more then 3 or some times less so the image view needs to be created in the for loop it self

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to modify `json` structure to make it much easier to parse? My proposal is to have array (`[ ... ]`) of objects (`{ ... }`). After that you no needed `size` and keys like `0`, `1`, `...`.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: But you did not respond to my question. Current json structure is not so good.

Comment: @Boken i can but m not sure i want to because it is very complicated at the moment

Comment: OK, so how many element can have this json? And How layout should look like when file will have e.g. 20 elements? Are you expecting 20 ImageViews? If yes, you should use `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Boken Yes i am but later those image views will be clickable i suppose

Comment: @Boken i will give the recycle view a shot then get back here if it works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, step by step in Kotlin.

My **json file** (in `res > raw > people.json`):

```
{
  "0": {
    "image_path": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485199692108-c3b5069de6a0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
    "title": "Girl 1"
  },
  "1": {
    "image_path": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520065949650-380765513210?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
    "title": "Girl 2"
  },
  "2": {
    "image_path": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547513609-d80733850d2e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
    "title": "Girl 3"
  },
  "3": {
    "image_path": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550094195-2234fa4e2128?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
    "title": "Girl 4"
  },
  "size": "4"
}
```

**Layout for Activity** (`res > layout > activity_main.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Our main activity of the appliaction** (`MainActivity.kt`)

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONObject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupUi()
    }

    private fun setupUi() {
        // Read file content
        val jsonFile = resources
            .openRawResource(R.raw.images)
            .bufferedReader()
            .readText()

        // Change "String" in to "Json Object"
        val root = JSONObject(jsonFile)

        // Get size of the list
        val size = root.getString("size").toInt()

        // Create (empty) list of people
        val peopleList = mutableListOf<Person>()

        // Loop to read all of the people
        for (position in 0 until size) {
            val element = root.getJSONObject(position.toString())

            // Change json in to Kotlin object
            val photo = Person(
                element.getString("image_path"),
                element.getString("title")
            )

            // Add element to the list
            peopleList.add(photo)
        }

        // Add adapter for RecyclerView
        recycler_view.adapter = PeopleAdapter(this, peopleList)
    }
}
```

**Element of the list (`res > layout > list_item.xml`)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_view" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Model class representing single element on the list (`Person.kt`)**

```
class Person(
    val image: String,
    val title: String
)
```

**Adapter** (using `ViewHolder` pattern)

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_item.view.*

class PeopleAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val listOfColor: List<Person>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PeopleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    // Creating elements (one item from list)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater
            .from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // Number of elements
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listOfColor.size

    // Fill elements with a data
    override fun onBindViewHolder(row: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        row.bind(position)
    }

    // Class responsible for one (single) row
    inner class ViewHolder(private val item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        fun bind(position: Int) {
            // Get image address
            val person = listOfColor[position]

            // Load image
            Glide.with(context).load(person.image).into(item.image_view)

            // Set text
            item.title.text = person.title
        }
    }
}
```

**Remember about three (3) dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

**And (1) persmission** in (manifest)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Colors** (in `res > values > colors.xml`)

```
<color name="colorWhite">#FFF</color>

<!-- Black with 50% transparency -->
<color name="colorBlack">#80000000</color>
```

And expected output:
[image]

Comment: Please accept answer or ask about something unclear 

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as a reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10593838/7586266
the idea is for you to iterate over the JSON objects you have "0" , "1" ,"2" ... etc

in order to do that go within the json object just like you entered size in here

```
jObj.getString("size")
```

and you can use the **i** in your for loop in order to get the jObj which contains your url 
like this

```
JSONObject jObj =  json.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i)); // where json is your whole json and you are getting the object "0","1" and "2" from it
string image_path_variable = jObj .getString("image_path");
```

and you can parse your JObj at i to a JSONObject which you can get the "image_path"
once you are able to do that you can use

```
Picasso.get().load(image_path_variable).into(your_desired_image_view);
```

Comment: i think i wasnt clear so my layout will have multiple image view depending on what the for loop has example of there are 3 images the page will have 3 images

Comment: @o3203823 are you using a recyclerview ? or in other words , adapter to generate imageviews ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
int size =  Integer.parseInt(jObj.getString("size"));   

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

   JSONObject itemObj = jObj.get(Integer.valueOf(i)).getAsJsonObject();
   String path = itemObj.getString("image_path")

   ImageView view = new ImageView(context);

   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

   layout.addView(view, params);

   Picasso.get().load(path).into(view);
}
```

Comment: i think i wasnt clear so my layout will have multiple image view depending on what the for loop has example of there are 3 images the page will have 3 images

Comment: bro i appreciate your answer but i dont think you are understanding my questions so what i am saying the my json wont always have 3 images somtimes it will have more then 3 or some times less so the image view needs to be created in the for loop it self 
thank you so much