# Discord.js Leaderboard for XP

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

In the last days I have developed a Leveling system. Im storing the Data in an JSON file, which is looking like this:

```
    {
      serverID{
         userID1{
          xp: 10;
          Level: 1
         },
         userID2{
          xp: 10;
          Level: 1
         }
      }
    }
```

Now I would like to make a leaderboard which is reading from this file. I have looked around in the Internet, but nothing worked. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a simple server XP leaderboard, you have to read your XP data file with the [fs library](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and parse it with JSON.

```
let data = Fs.readFileSync("path-to-json-file", "utf8");
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then, just [iterate the keys of your ServerID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject) object, and inside the loop, sort them with the following function:

```
function sortMyArray() {
    arrayName.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b-a;
    });
}
```

Finally, just join the array's elements, send the message containing a bit of markdown and you'll be good to go!

```
message.channel.send(`\`\`\`markdown\n# Leaderboard of the server \n${levels.join("\n")}\`\`\``);
```

Comment: It shows `message.channel.send(`\`\`\`markdown\n# Leaderboard of the server \n${levels.join("\n")}\`\`\``);
                                                                                     ^

TypeError: levels.join is not a function`

Comment: In fact, "levels" was an example array name - just insert in your code ```[your array name].join(code)```

Comment: Now got this as an output: [Have no space to upload it here xD](https://www.memebotdc.de/Pics/example1.jpg) by [this](https://www.memebotdc.de/Pics/example2.jpg) code

Comment: You closed the ```}``` before the ```.join()```.
Here is the correct line: ```${levles[message.guild.id].join(" ")}```
If my post helped, don't forget to upvote it ;)

Comment: Now got this ` message.channel.send(`\`\`\`markdown\n# Leaderboard of the server \n${levles[message.guild.id].join("\n")}\`\`\``);                                                                                                       ^

TypeError: levles[message.guild.id].join is not a function`

sorry if im amnoying xD

Comment: You can check [this file](https://github.com/Ma15fo43/Mango/blob/master/src/commands/levelboard.ts) if you still need help.

Comment: I dont think that this is discord.js... But thanks for your Help

Comment: No problem - if you still need help, just reply to this comment, I'm here to help.