# Java Generics with "extends"

Tags: java, generics

Instead of using if/else I'd like to use a map to get a concrete implementation.

I'd like to use generics to declare a specific entity handler witch handles a specific entity but I have the problem that the handler just accepts extensions of my entity interface. The code looks like this:

```java
private Map<Class<IEntity>, IEntityHandler> handlers;

public void callingMethod(IModel model) {
  for (IEntity entity : model.getObjects()) {
    // handle accepts just IDevice and not IEntity !
    handlers.get(entity).handle(entity);
  }
}

public interface IEntityHandler<T extends IEntity> {
  handle(T entity);
}

public class DeviceHandler implements IEntityHandler<IDevice> {
  @Override
  public void handle(IDevice deviceEntity) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

How can I get my handle method that it takes IEntity's? IDevice extends from IEntity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare you map as:

```
Map<Class<T extends IEntity>, IEntityHandler> handlers.
```

Comment: I don't think he has a type parameter `T` in the class that has the map as field. This wouldn't be possible since the map should be capable of containing handlers for a variety of different classes. That's the whole purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need to change this line...

```
handlers.get(entity).handle(entity);
```

to this...

```
handlers.get(entity.getClass()).handle(entity);
```

Then, like the others said, it'd be best to change the `Class<IEntity>` type parameter of your map to `Class<? extends IEntity>`, since you want to map concrete classes to handlers.

If you do it like that, you won't get an error. Only a warning because the `IEntityHandler` type parameter in your map is a raw type. But if you try to change it to `? extends IEntityHandler` or `IEntityHandler<? extends IEntity>`, you will get a compilation error on assigning or populating the Map.

So I suggest you just make the above to changes (`getClass()` and `Class<? extends IEntity>`), then simply suppress the warning with an annotation. As long as your Map is properly populated with the right handler for the right class, you won't run into trouble.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<? extends IEntity, ? extends IEntityHandler> handlers;
```

Comment: He needs to map `Class` objects to handlers, not instances of `IEntity` to handlers.

Comment: Here I get this build error: The method handle(capture#1-of ? extends IEntity) in the type IEntityHandler<capture#1-of ? extends IEntity> is not applicable for the arguments (IEntity)

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<Class<? extends IEntity>, ? extends IEntityHandler> handlers;
```

Comment: This will lead to issues when trying to actually place handlers in the map. Using `? extends ...` for a type param in a collection declaration usually doesn't work well when you intend to directly add entries to the collection for the reasons [explained here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: Same here the build error: The method handle(capture#1-of ? extends IEntity) in the type IEntityHandler<capture#1-of ? extends IEntity> is not applicable for the arguments (IEntity)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're heading towards is a (deep breath) [typesafe hetereogeneous container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540/java-map-with-values-limited-by-keys-type-parameter). However, because the objects you want to store are themselves generic, you need to use [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

I think you then need to introduce and then tame a wildcard by rewriting the top loop like this:

```
for (IEntity entity: model.getObjects()) {
    handle(entity);
}

private <T extends IEntity> handle(T entity) {
    IEntityHandler<T> handler = ... get appropriate handler from THC ...
    handler.handle(entity);
}
```

I'm not sure about this, though. This is a pretty rough sketch.