# Java - Typesafe heterogeneous container pattern to store Functions

Tags: java, generics

This is an extension to [Java map with values limited by key's type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540/java-map-with-values-limited-by-keys-type-parameter/416611#416611). However, I am trying to use the `Map` to store a `Function`.

```
private static Map<Class<?>, Function<?, JSONObject>> serializers = new HashMap<>();

private static <T> void addSerializer(Class<T> klass, Function<T, JSONObject> fn) {
    serializers.put(klass, fn);
}

private static <T> Function<T, JSONObject> getSerializer(Class<T> klass) {
    return (Function<T, JSONObject>) serializers.get(klass);
}

static {
    // add entries with addSerializer
}

public static JSONObject serialize(Object object) {
    Class<?> klass = object.getClass();

    return serializers.get(klass).apply(klass.cast(object));
}
```

I followed the pattern described in the linked SO question, but I am running into an issue on the last line, where I am trying to call the `apply` method for the `Function` stored in the `Map`.

The error message I am getting is

```
The method apply(capture#6-of ?) in the type Function<capture#6-of ?,JSONObject> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#7-of ?)
```

Is there anything I can do to get around this, or is there another structure I could use to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I suspect the two type of ? are being seen as the same one. You probably want to create another class to define the Function instead of defining their generics in the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some magic to let the compiler know that the `klass` is the `Class` representing `object`-s type:

```
public static JSONObject serialize(Object object) {
    Class cls = object.getClass();
    return serialize(cls, cls.cast(object));
}

private static <T> JSONObject serialize(Class<T> klass, T object) {
    return getSerializer(klass).apply(object);
}
```

The first `serialize` method retrieves the class (or throws a `NullPointerException`), then casts the object to its own type, and then invokes the second `serialize` method. Now, the second `serialize` method has its own type parameter, `T`, so it can safely invoke the `Function.apply`.

Unfortunately, we need this kind of indirection to let the compiler know that the `klass` runtime type token is the one that belongs to the actual object.