# Unresolved reference: T

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create a data class:

```
data class MyClass(val b: Boolean,
               val s: String,
               val flags: Map<Key<T>, T>)
```

This does not compile due to "Unresolved reference: T"

In the `flags` map, I need to have `Key<String>, String` and `Key<Int>, Int` pairs, but NOT `Key<String>, Int`

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What is `Key` here?

Comment: In this case, Key is android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest.Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this directly through the type system, you will have to use encapsulation to ensure the types of key and value are consistent. [This problem exists in Java as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540)

The solution given by others doesn't work, since you'd only be able to put one type of key/value into the map (the idea of having a `Map<Key<T>, T>` is somewhat flawed):

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Key<String>, String>() // what to put as generic params here?
map[Key<String>()] = "blah" // works
map[Key<Int>()] = 3 // doesn't work!
map[Key<Int>()] = "blah" // compiler error (as intended)
```

or:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Key<*>, Any?>()
map[Key<String>()] = "blah" // works
map[Key<Int>()] = 3 // works
map[Key<Int>()] = "blah" // works, but is wrong.
```

You'd have to for instance write your own encapsulation around a map that ensures a key always matches a value:

```
class MutableKeyMap {
    private val map = mutableMapOf<Key<*>, Any?>() // private / encapsulated

    operator fun <T> get(key: Key<T>): T {
        return map[key] as T
    }

    operator fun <T> set(key: Key<T>, value: T): Unit { // Key's T must match value's type.
        map[key] = value
    }
}
```

(You could add an immutable super-interface if you'd like)

And then use that as a field:

```
data class MyClass(val b: Boolean,
               val s: String,
               val flags: MutableKeyMap)
```

...

```
val map = MutableKeyMap()
map[Key<String>()] = "blah" // works
map[Key<Int>()] = 3 // works
map[Key<Int>()] = "blah" // compiler error (as intended)
```

Comment: I've started working on something very similar to what you are suggesting. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You must define the generic for the class:

```
data class MyClass<T>(val b: Boolean,
               val s: String,
               val flags: Map<Key<T>, T>)
```

Comment: I feel like that's not going to work. If I'll have MyClass<Any>, wouldn't that allow a `Key<String>, Int` pair?

Comment: @Mugur `T` is invariant, so no... Besides, can't you test it? That would only work if you had `flags: Map<out Key<out T>, T>`

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten about this:

```
 data class MyClass<T>(val b: Boolean,
 // ----------------^
               val s: String,
               val flags: Map<Key<T>, T>)
```

*For more info: [Generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generics)*